# Edit TikZ Chains to add labels and maintain the option to add individual styles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, node-connections

I find a [code](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/labeled-chain/) that redefines the way one defines a chain (`\chainin`), and allows one to include labels in the chains. However, this code disables the style options (`by` and `with` keyword). However, I need to give individual styles to each chain.

How can I add individual styles to each chain, and at the same time being able to tag the connections by adding a node, like: `node [left] {tag}`. So I'm aiming for something like this: `\chainin (node) [join=by myStyle, {node [left] {my Tag}}];`

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,chains,scopes,matrix}
% This code makes it able to include the tag
\makeatletter
\tikzset{join/.code=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
  decision/.style = {draw,
                     diamond,
                     text badly centered,
                     fill          = blue!5,
                     text width    = 15mm,
                     node distance = 2.5cm,
                     inner sep     = 0pt},
  block/.style    = {draw,
                     rectangle,
                     text centered,
                     rounded corners,
                     fill           = blue!5,
                     text width     = 20mm,
                     minimum height = 10mm},
  tip/.style      = {->,
                     very thick,
                     color = black!50}
]

\matrix[row sep=1cm]{
\node [block] (blk) {A block here}; \\
\node [decision] (dec) {Is something?};\\
};

{ [start chain]
  \chainin (blk);
  % By removing the 'by tip' style this compiles
  \chainin (dec) [join=by tip, {node [left] {yes}}];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've added a [feature request to TikZ for this](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3539373&group_id=142562&atid=752795). Feel free to improve it with comments!

Comment: @sampablokuper maybe they can implement (fix) the initial idea I proposed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41474/7561)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after analyzing the [solution of wh1t3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41361/7561), and the chains library, I tried to implement a solution that allow me to use the `join` code and add the labels.

I'm not sure if this is a correct approach, because I never done this before, so let me know if there is a better way. I redefined the functions of the library to allow the `label` keyword to be added, and it will add the node with the label that I'm missing. The code to be added is:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@parse@join#1{%
  \def\tikz@temp{#1}%
  \ifx\tikz@temp\pgfutil@empty%
    \tikz@lib@parse@join@by by \pgf@stop%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@in@{with }{#1}% 
    \ifpgfutil@in@% 'with [by] [label]'
      \pgfutil@in@{by }{#1}%
      \ifpgfutil@in@% 'with by [label]'
        \pgfutil@in@{label }{#1}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@% 'with by label'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@with@by@label#1\pgf@stop%
        \else% 'with by'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@with@by#1\pgf@stop%
        \fi%
      \else% 'with [label]'
        \pgfutil@in@{label }{#1}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@% 'with label'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@with@label#1\pgf@stop%
        \else% with
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@with@by#1 by \pgf@stop%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \else% '[by] [label]'
      \pgfutil@in@{by }{#1}%
      \ifpgfutil@in@% 'by [label]'
        \pgfutil@in@{label }{#1}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@% 'by label'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@by@label#1\pgf@stop%
        \else% 'by'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@by#1\pgf@stop%
        \fi%
      \else% '[label]'
        \pgfutil@in@{label }{#1}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@% 'label'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@label#1\pgf@stop%
        \else%
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@by#1 by \pgf@stop%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\def\tikz@lib@parse@join@with@by@label with #1 by #2 label #3\pgf@stop{%
  \tikzset{after node path={(#1)edge[every join,#2]#3(\tikzchaincurrent)}}%
}
\def\tikz@lib@parse@join@with@label with #1 label #2\pgf@stop{%
  \tikzset{after node path={(#1)edge[every join]#2(\tikzchaincurrent)}}%
}
\def\tikz@lib@parse@join@by@label by #1 label #2\pgf@stop{%
  \tikzset{after node path={\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)edge[every join,#1]#2(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}%
}
\def\tikz@lib@parse@join@label label #1\pgf@stop{%
  \tikzset{after node path={\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}%
}
\makeatother
```

After adding that part, now I'm able to call my `chainin` like:

```
\chainin (node) [join=with anotherNode by myStyle label {node[above] {some Tag}}];
\chainin (node) [join=by myStyle label {node[above] {some Tag}}];
```

A full example would be

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,chains,scopes,matrix}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@parse@join#1{%
  \def\tikz@temp{#1}%
  \ifx\tikz@temp\pgfutil@empty%
    \tikz@lib@parse@join@by by \pgf@stop%
  \else%
    \pgfutil@in@{with }{#1}% 
    \ifpgfutil@in@% 'with [by] [label]'
      \pgfutil@in@{by }{#1}%
      \ifpgfutil@in@% 'with by [label]'
        \pgfutil@in@{label }{#1}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@% 'with by label'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@with@by@label#1\pgf@stop%
        \else% 'with by'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@with@by#1\pgf@stop%
        \fi%
      \else% 'with [label]'
        \pgfutil@in@{label }{#1}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@% 'with label'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@with@label#1\pgf@stop%
        \else% with
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@with@by#1 by \pgf@stop%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \else% '[by] [label]'
      \pgfutil@in@{by }{#1}%
      \ifpgfutil@in@% 'by [label]'
        \pgfutil@in@{label }{#1}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@% 'by label'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@by@label#1\pgf@stop%
        \else% 'by'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@by#1\pgf@stop%
        \fi%
      \else% '[label]'
        \pgfutil@in@{label }{#1}%
        \ifpgfutil@in@% 'label'
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@label#1\pgf@stop%
        \else%
          \tikz@lib@parse@join@by#1 by \pgf@stop%
        \fi%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\def\tikz@lib@parse@join@with@by@label with #1 by #2 label #3\pgf@stop{%
  \tikzset{after node path={(#1)edge[every join,#2]#3(\tikzchaincurrent)}}%
}
\def\tikz@lib@parse@join@with@label with #1 label #2\pgf@stop{%
  \tikzset{after node path={(#1)edge[every join]#2(\tikzchaincurrent)}}%
}
\def\tikz@lib@parse@join@by@label by #1 label #2\pgf@stop{%
  \tikzset{after node path={\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)edge[every join,#1]#2(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}%
}
\def\tikz@lib@parse@join@label label #1\pgf@stop{%
  \tikzset{after node path={\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)edge[every join]#1(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
  decision/.style = {draw,
                     diamond,
                     text badly centered,
                     fill          = blue!5,
                     text width    = 15mm,
                     node distance = 2.5cm,
                     inner sep     = 0pt},
  block/.style    = {draw,
                     rectangle,
                     text centered,
                     rounded corners,
                     fill           = blue!5,
                     text width     = 20mm,
                     minimum height = 10mm},
  tip/.style      = {->,
                     very thick,
                     color = black!50},
  tip2/.style      = {->,
                     very thick,
                     bend right,
                     color = black!50}
]

\matrix[row sep=1cm]{
\node [block] (blk) {A block here}; \\
\node [decision] (dec) {Is something?};\\
\node [block] (blk2) {Another block};\\
};

{ [start chain]
  \chainin (blk);
  % Removing the 'by tip' style this compiles
  \chainin (dec) [join=by tip label {node [left] {yes}}];
  \chainin (blk2) [join=by tip];
  \chainin (blk2) [join=with blk by {tip2} label {node[left]{my tag}}];
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the join is not used as a parametrized style, but the code is ran. That is, `by tip, {node [left] {yes}}` becomes `#1` in `join/.code` and so it's placed after `edge[every join]`. That means that without the `tip` it would work fine, the node is placed after the edge and is applied as you would expect. The problem is that you want the `tip` to be placed as an option on the edge besides `every join`. The easiest way to accomplish this is to let `join` take two arguments, one to go in the edge options and another to represent possible nodes. This can be achieved by the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,chains,scopes,matrix}
% This code makes it able to include the tag
\makeatletter
\tikzset{join/.code 2 args=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join,#1]#2(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
  decision/.style = {draw,
                     diamond,
                     text badly centered,
                     fill          = blue!5,
                     text width    = 15mm,
                     node distance = 2.5cm,
                     inner sep     = 0pt},
  block/.style    = {draw,
                     rectangle,
                     text centered,
                     rounded corners,
                     fill           = blue!5,
                     text width     = 20mm,
                     minimum height = 10mm},
  tip/.style      = {->,
                     very thick,
                     color = black!50}
]

\matrix[row sep=1cm]{
\node [block] (blk) {A block here}; \\
\node [decision] (dec) {Is something?};\\
};

{ [start chain]
  \chainin (blk);
  %tip and node:
  \chainin (dec) [join={tip}{node [left] {yes}}];
  %Only the tip:
  %\chainin (dec) [join={tip}{}];
  %Only the node:
  %\chainin (dec) [join={}{node [left] {yes}}];
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see you can just leave the arguments empty if you don't want a specific part of the join.

**Edit:** I don't see a way to accomplish this. Since you have to change the `code` for the `join` key in order to get the desired behaviour. But to get the `with .. by ...` behaviour different code is required. Unfortunately you can only have one "code-related" key as far as I know (that is, TikZ can't determine which code to call depending on the parameters). The easiest way is probably to change the new `join` method introduced in the code above to `myjoin` and use that wherever you want labeling. So the `tikzset` would become:

```
tikzset{myjoin/.code 2 args=\tikzset{after node path={%
\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty\else(\tikzchainprevious)%
edge[every join,#1]#2(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}
```

Then you can use the `myjoin={options}{labeling node}` where you need labeling and `join=with ... by ...` where you need the old behaviour. It might be wise to choose a more apropriate name than `myjoin` though.

If you like this verbose (and perhaps more readable) way of working with keys, you can define the `myjoin` option as follows:

```
\tikzset{myjoin/.code args={style #1 and label #2}{%
\tikzset{after node path={\ifx\tikzchainprevious\pgfutil@empty%
\else(\tikzchainprevious)edge[every join,#1]#2(\tikzchaincurrent)\fi}}}}
```

Which can be used as

```
\chainin (dec) [myjoin=style tip and label {node [left] {yes}}];
```

Comment: Very good! Pedro commented similar on [this blog post](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/maths/pgf-tikz-commutative-diagram/). I remember I tested it and could not make it compilable, perhaps a version issue then.

Comment: @StefanKottwitz: I see, That is very similar indeed. I am not sure why he leaves out the `every join` style on the edge, since that is a nice way to get some default behaviour on the edges. I don't know enough about when which command was introduced to be able to comment on whether or not it could have been a version issue. Perhaps the key management interface was less advanced in older versions.

Comment: This solves the issue of adding the style, but now the normal `join` behavior isn't working. Is there a way to have both worlds? That is, being able to use the `join=by... with...` command and the `join={style}{node...}` new definition in the same diagram?

Comment: @adn: not exactly, see the edited answer though.

Comment: Thanks, the verbose part makes it more readable. I think that having two keys is OK. The problem was that I have to modify all the other paths that aren't using labels. Your explanation helps a lot.