# Drawing multiple arrows at arbitrary angles in a common direction, with overlap

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I am trying to draw a diagram with `tikz` that has multiple arrows (here I have 4) between nodes, where the nodes are placed arbitrarily in a diagram. My best (that is, shortest and easiest to understand) solution has been to use the `draw` option `double`, but this creates unwanted overlap of the arrows, as in I cannot see the arrows below other arrows, and I would like to see all of them.

My current situation has the below code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,minimum size=8ex,fill=white}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (x) at (0,0) {};
\coordinate (1) at ($(x) + (125:2)$) ;
\coordinate (2) at ($(x) + (55:2)$) ;
\coordinate (3) at ($(x) + (350:2)$);
\coordinate (t1) at ($(x) + (190:2)$);
\foreach \i\j in {1/2,2/3,1/t1,2/t1,1/3,3/t1} {
    \draw[draw=black,double distance=15pt] (\i) to (\j);
    \draw[draw=black,double distance=5pt] (\i) to (\j);}
\node[state] (1a) at (1) {1};
\node[state] (2a) at (2) {2};
\node[state] (3a) at (3) {3};
\node[state] (t1a) at (t1) {3};
\draw[loosely dotted,ultra thick] ($(x)+(290:1.8)$) to [bend left=30] ($(x)+(250:1.8)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Yielding the following result:

[image]

I want to see all the arrow lines, not just the ones drawn last.

This situation happens because with the `double` option two lines are actually drawn, one thinner than the other, the inside one being colored white. Looking at some similar questions here, the solutions were either case-specific or used `nodename.west` or similar directions along with a `\foreach` loop and some `\yshift` commands. However, since my arrows do not all go either horizontally or vertically, and I would like the normal distance between two adjacent arrows to be the same throughout, and since I am not a `tikz` whiz, I could not adjust those solutions to my needs.

Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Comment: You sure you want the lines being parallel?  I could see it looking real nice originating at one point but ending up at different points using the `to` syntax.

Comment: @PeterGrill Each node in the diagram is supposed to represent a group of vertices of a graph, and the edges are all possible edges between two groups of vertices. So I guess parallel isn't necessary (though I like how it looks), but I don't want all arrows coming out of/going into a single coordinate. However, I think that if they all start at the center of one of the nodes, it might work at creating the desired impression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Furnishing further with Jake's PSTricks' `ncbar` equivalent style (from [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/is-there-a-tikz-equivalent-to-the-pstricks-ncbar-command) ), it's possible to draw `2n` lines instead of `n` double lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    mystate/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,minimum size=8ex,fill=white}
    ]
\def\mylabellist{{1,2,3,"$t-1$"}}
\foreach \x[count=\y] in{125,55,350,190}{\coordinate (n\y) at (\x:2);}

\foreach \x in {1,...,3}{
    \foreach \y in {\x,...,4}{
        \foreach \zz in {90,-90}{
            \draw (n\x) to[ncbar=0.1cm,ncbar angle=\zz] (n\y);
            \draw (n\x) to[ncbar=0.3cm,ncbar angle=\zz] (n\y);
        }
    }
}
\foreach \y in{1,...,4}{\node[mystate] (n\y a) at (n\y)
{\pgfmathparse{\mylabellist[\number\numexpr\y-1\relax]}\pgfmathresult};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]