# Adding a label to a bent arrow in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

In this question [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068/2693) Jake provided a very nice TikZ version of the PSTricks `\ncbar` command.

With normal node connections in TikZ, I can use the `[auto]` parameter to automatically place nodes along paths.  I'd like to be able to do this using the `\ncbar` path, but I'm not sure how.

So in the code below, I'd like to add a C node along the bent arrow similar to the C node added to the straight arrow.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}
\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
   \node (A) at (1,4) {A};
   \node (B) at (3,4) {B};
   \draw[->] (A) to  node {C} (B);
   \draw[->] (A) to [ncbar=-1.5em] node {C} (B); % can I get this to work?
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add `\tikztonodes` to the path construction in the main link.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$) 
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$) 
           \tikztonodes
        -- (\tikztotarget) 
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}
\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
   \node (A) at (1,4) {A};
   \node (B) at (3,4) {B};
   \draw[->] (A) to  node {C} (B);
   \draw[->] (A) to [ncbar=-1.5em] node[pos=0.3,below] {C} (B); 
   \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]