# How to add label to bent arrow without manual adjustment?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

Here is my flowchart and I want to add labels L1,L2, and L3 to the bent arrows.  Though following code worked (ref: [Adding a label to a bent arrow in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80169/adding-a-label-to-a-bent-arrow-in-tikz))

\draw [arrow]  (b8.south)++(.3,0) |- ++(0,-1.5) -| node[pos=0.225,above] {L3}  (b7);

But it requires manual adjustment of position. Is there an efficient way to work around this issue?

[image]

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `auto` and `midway` option for the node to place the label automatically:

```
\draw [arrow] (b8.south)++(.3,0) |- ++(0,-1.5) -| node[midway,auto] {L3} (b7);
```

**EDIT**: How to include L1 and L2 nodes. We replace `auto` by the positioning of the node we want: either `left` or `right`. There can also be a way to define the right level at which `|-` arrows meet. Or you can extract the y-component of `b11` node using the `let` operation, which I have done here. You will need to use the `calc` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{every node/.append style={inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,
minimum height=1cm,minimum width=2cm,draw},
Lnode/.style={outer sep=#1,inner sep=1mm,
minimum size=0pt,draw=green,fill=green,text=red}};
%
\node[draw=red,ultra thick] (b8) at (5cm,0) {B8};
\node[minimum width=0pt,inner sep=1mm] (b9) at (2,0) {B9};
\node[draw=blue,ultra thick] (b10) at (-1cm,0) {B10};
\node (b11) at (2cm,-2cm) {B11};
% Using let operation to extract the exact coordinates for B-nodes
\draw[->] let \p1=(b11.center),\p2=(b10.center) in
(b10.south) -- (\x2,\y1) node[Lnode=1mm,midway,left]{L1} -- (b11.west);
\draw[<-] let \p1=(b11.center),\p2=(b8.center) in
(b8.south) -- (\x2,\y1) node[Lnode=1mm,midway,right]{L2} -- (b11.east);
\draw[->] (b8) -- (b9); \draw[->] (b9) -- (b10);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:
[image: Automaton node labelling]

Comment: Your solution puts L3 at right place. Can L1 and L2 be done in a similar manner?

Comment: Definitely, just have to include these options for those nodes. SinceB the L1, L2, L3 are different in node style to B8,B9, etc., we make a different node style for them. This time we do not use `auto`, but choose where to place the L-nodes: either `left` or `right`, as preferred. I have updated my answer to include L1 and L2.