# Parallel line segments connecting points in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Assume that we have two coordinates `(a)` and `(b)`. I want to draw a line which is a *parallel translation* of the line which connects `(a)` and `(b)`.

I would like to have something like `\drawparallel{a}{b}{dist}` which will draw a line parallel to the one connecting `(a)` and `(b)` at (*signed!*) distance `dist`.

I tried many things both based on `\newcommand`  and on `\tikzset` but could not make it work.

Edit: To make it clearer, I want the the four points (two of the original line segment, and two of its translated copy) will form a **rectangle**.

Comment: What's parallel? Is `\draw ([xshit=dist]a)--([xhsift=dist]b);` enough?

Comment: @Ignasi: Actually no. With your solution the four points (two of the original curve and two of the translated one) form (in general) a parallelogram. I want them to form a *rectangle*.

Comment: You can use this one but without the connecting lines http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/is-there-a-tikz-equivalent-to-the-pstricks-ncbar-command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, as pointed out by @percusse, [Jake's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55069/412) solved my problem. In particular, I added the following

```
\tikzset{
      ncbar/.style={
        to path=%
        ($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$)!90:(\tikztostart)$)
      },
      ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
    }
```

Then,

```
\draw (a) -- (b);
\draw (a) to[ncbar=1] (b);
```

yielded the right result.

[image]

Comment: It is simpler to specify the end of the parallel path as `($(\tikztotarget)!#1!270:(\tikztostart)$)`