# Draw offset of polylines

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm afraid that I have a followup question to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/116984/412).

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]
    \tikzset{
      ncbar/.style={
        to path=%
        ($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!90:(\tikztotarget)$)!90:(\tikztostart)$)
      },
      ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
    }

    \draw[red,ultra thin] (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (2,0);
    \draw[blue,ultra thin] (0,0) to[ncbar=0.25cm] (1,2) to[ncbar=0.25cm] (2,0);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which yields:
[image]

Note that the source of the second part of the blue path is not "correct". In turn, the second blue part is *not* parallel to the red counterpart. How can I fix this? Somehow reset/set `\tikztostart`?

**Bonus question:** How can I bridge the gap between the two blue parts using the missing part of a circle arc (this circle centered at the apex of the red curve and of radius `0.25cm` in this example)?

Comment: Are your sure that your example works. I am getting the error: `! Package tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: I re-pasted the code and double-checked. Works for me.

Answer (score 11):

You have to include the final `(\tikztotarget)` in the `to path` definition (without the preceding `--`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.25]
\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}

    \draw[red,ultra thin] (0,0) -- (1,2) -- (2,0);
    \draw[blue,ultra thin] (0,0) to[ncbar=0.25cm] (1,2) to[ncbar=0.25cm] (2,0);

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. I'll wait to see if someone will add something regarding the bonus part :)