# "perpendicular shift" for paths

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I am trying to draw several parallel arrows between the same nodes, to get roughly this result:

[image: Desired result]

What I would need is a hypothetical `perpendicular shift` key, which would shift the edge along its perpendicular. Using `xshift` works for the vertical lines, but not the horizontal ones, and vice versa for `yshift`.

I tried using `decorate,decoration={lineto,raise=0.1cm}`, but it seems to have no effect on the path. It kinda works with `decorate,decoration={brace, amplitude=0,raise=0.1cm}`, but it feels a bit clunky, and the arrow heads are all pointing upwards:

[image: Result with brace decoration (the arrowheads all point upwards)]

@Torbjørn T. mentionned [this very similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116996/5699), which gets the line distance and arrowheads right, but alters the line length (the lines start and end near the nodes' centers, instead of starting near their borders):

[image: The red and blue lines start near the node's center]

Here's the code for the `brace` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  rel1/.style={->, red,   decorate,decoration={brace, amplitude=0,raise=0.1cm}},
  rel2/.style={->, green, },
  rel3/.style={->, blue,  decorate,decoration={brace, amplitude=0,raise=-0.1cm}}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (Z) at (0,0) {0};
  \node (A) at (0,1) {A};
  \node (B) at (1,1) {B};
  \node (C) at (1,0) {C};

  \draw[rel1] (Z) to (A);
  \draw[rel1] (Z) to (B);
  \draw[rel1] (Z) to (C);

  \draw[rel2] (Z) to (A);
  \draw[rel2] (Z) to (B);
  \draw[rel2] (Z) to (C);

  \draw[rel3] (Z) to (A);
  \draw[rel3] (Z) to (B);
  \draw[rel3] (Z) to (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm looking for a solution that can be used simply as a style on the whole path, and doesn't require knowing the angle of the line where it is used.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116984/parallel-line-segments-connecting-points-in-tikz/116996#116996

Answer (score 3):

Defining a custom path decoration seems to work, although I'm not sure I did everything as it should, so bugs may arise in corner cases.

[image: Result using the "simple line" decoration]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{simple line}{start}
{
  \state{start}[width = +0pt,
                next state=step]{
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{step}[auto end on length    = 3pt,
               auto corner on length = 3pt,               
               width=+1pt]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1pt}{0pt}}
  }
  \state{final}
  {}
}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  rel1/.style={->, red,   decorate,decoration={simple line, raise=0.1cm}},
  rel2/.style={->, green, },
  rel3/.style={->, blue,  decorate,decoration={simple line, raise=-0.1cm}}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (Z) at (0,0) {0};
  \node (A) at (0,1) {A};
  \node (B) at (1,1) {B};
  \node (C) at (1,0) {C};

  \draw[rel1] (Z) to (A);
  \draw[rel1] (Z) to (B);
  \draw[rel1] (Z) to (C);

  \draw[rel2] (Z) to (A);
  \draw[rel2] (Z) to (B);
  \draw[rel2] (Z) to (C);

  \draw[rel3] (Z) to (A);
  \draw[rel3] (Z) to (B);
  \draw[rel3] (Z) to (C);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```