# Draw snapped off arrows / arrows with corners between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have three nodes and want to connect two nodes with an arrow that is bent like in my paint drawing. I also need to include some text above the arrow.

[image]

This is my stripped down code for generating the nodes:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=none,fill=none, text height=1em] (1) {test1};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, text height=1em] (2) [right=.6cm of 1 ]{test2};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, text height=1em] (3) [right=.6cm of 2]{test3};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the past, I've connected nodes with a curve, like this:

```
\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (3)edge [bend angle=90] node[above left] {foo} (1);
```

Unfortunately I can't adapt this code to look like the picture above.

I guess I could insert "invisible" nodes to fake the corners of the arrow, but TikZ might have a simple option for my desired output, that I wasn't able to find?

Comment: You might find interesting [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068/13304)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a possible solution where the vertical height due to `+(0,1)` can be changed to suit one's need.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=none,fill=none, text height=1em] (1) {test1};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, text height=1em] (2) [right=.6cm of 1 ]{test2};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, text height=1em] (3) [right=.6cm of 2]{test3};
\draw (3.north) -- +(0,1)-| node[above right]{Text starts from there} (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=none,fill=none, text height=1em] (1) {test1};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, text height=1em] (2) [right=.6cm of 1 ]{test2};
\node[draw=none,fill=none, text height=1em] (3) [right=.6cm of 2]{test3};
\draw[->, every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}] 
   (3) -- ($(3)+(0,.5)$) -- ($(1)+(0,.5)$) node[above, pos=0.8] {some text} -- (1) ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

For fun, here is a non`tikz` version.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\leftbentarrow[4][]{\setstackgap{L}{.3\baselineskip}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#2}%
  \def\stackalignment{r}\stackon{#2}{\def\stackalignment{l}%
    \stackon[-.2pt]{\makebox[0pt]{$\downarrow$}}%
    {\trlap{\textcolor{cyan}{\sffamily#1}}\rule{.5\wd0}{.4pt}}}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#3}%
  \setbox1=\hbox{$\downarrow$}%
  \def\stackalignment{c}\stackon[\Sstackgap+\dp1+\ht1-.2pt]{#3}{\rule{\wd0}{.4pt}}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{#4}%
  \def\stackalignment{l}\stackon{#4}{\def\stackalignment{r}%
    \stackon[-.2pt]{\makebox[0pt]{\rule{.4pt}{\ht1+\dp1}}}{\rule{.5\wd0}{.4pt}}}%
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
\leftbentarrow[some text]{test1}{ test2 test2a }{test3}

\leftbentarrow[some text]{test1}{\makebox[1in]{test2}}{test3}
\end{document}
```

[image]