# How to simplify path?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following MWE:

```
    \documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
         \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
         \coordinate (b) at (1,-1);
         \newlength{\vsep}
         \setlength{\vsep}{0.5cm}
         \coordinate (abovea) at ($(a) + (0,\vsep)$);
         \coordinate (aboveb) at (b |- abovea);
         \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt] at (a) {};
         \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt] at (b) {};
         \draw (a) -- (abovea) -- (aboveb) -- (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

It's quit verbose just to connect the points A and B and I am wondering how I can simplify it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the methods mentioned in [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55068/is-there-a-tikz-equivalent-to-the-pstricks-ncbar-command), you could simplify your code to

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt] (a) at (0,0) {};
  \node[fill=black,circle,inner sep=2pt] (b) at (1,-1) {};
  \draw (a) |- ($(a-|b) + (0,0.5cm)$) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here, `(a-|b)` is the point that has the y-coordinate of `a` and the x-coordinate of `b`. Using `|-` instead of `--` means, first move vertically to the y-coord of the second point, then horizontally to the point.

Comment: Two more options without using `calc` library: `\draw (a) --++(90:.5)-|(b);` or `\draw(a) --([yshift=.5cm]a.center)-|(b);`.