# Tikz: two edges path connection

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, edge

Is it possible to have a two-edge path, as in the picture below?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{status} = [rectangle, draw=black, text centered, anchor=north, text=black, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em, node distance=6ex and 7em, font=\bfseries]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw,thick,-latex]
\tikzstyle{transition} = [font=\small]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [status, fill=green] (T) {H};
\node [status, fill=red, right=5em of T] (A) {A};
\node [status, fill=gray, right=5em of A] (D) {D};

\path [line] (T) -- (A) node[transition,pos=0.5,above,align=left] {$\#A \geq 1$};
\path [line] (A) -- (D) node[transition,pos=0.5,above,align=left] {wait $\tau$ tick\\$\tau\sim\mathcal{G}(\lambda)$};
%\path [line] (D) -| (T) node[transition,pos=0.83,left] {$p_{repl}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

How I would like it:

[image: mockup]

Comment: In addition to Gonzalo's answer, see [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068)

Comment: Just noticed I duplicated it, sorry! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054162/tikz-two-edge-path/31214285#31214285

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
\path [line] (D) -- ++(0,-30pt) -| (T) node[transition,pos=0.83,left] {$p_{repl}$};
```

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{status} = [rectangle, draw=black, text centered, anchor=north, text=black, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em, node distance=6ex and 7em, font=\bfseries]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw,thick,-latex]
\tikzstyle{transition} = [font=\small]

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node [status, fill=green] (T) {H};
\node [status, fill=red, right=5em of T] (A) {A};
\node [status, fill=gray, right=5em of A] (D) {D};

\path [line] (T) -- (A) node[transition,pos=0.5,above,align=left] {$\#A \geq 1$};
\path [line] (A) -- (D) node[transition,pos=0.5,above,align=left] {wait $\tau$ tick\\$\tau\sim\mathcal{G}(\lambda)$};

\path [line] (D) -- ++(0,-30pt) -| (T) node[transition,pos=0.83,left] {$p_{repl}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was just about to reply to my own question, because I remembered meanwhile of adding a \coordinate below one node and do \draw (D.south) -| (mid) -| (T). But yours even nice, thank you!