# Tikz- Transitions around whole automaton

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata, transition

I have following automaton in Tikz:

[image]

Is it possible to do a transition similar to this one?

[image]

Here's my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,node distance=2.7cm,auto]
    \node[state,initial,accepting]  (I)                      {$I$};
    \node[state]                    (p) [above right of = I] {$p$};
    \node[state]                    (q) [right of = p]       {$q$};
    \node[state]                    (r) [below right of = I] {$r$};
    \node[state,accepting]          (F) [below right of = q] {$F$};

    \path[->]
        (I) edge                    node {a}     (p)
            edge                    node {b}     (r)
        (p) edge                    node {b}     (q)
            edge [swap, bend right] node {abc}   (F)
        (q) edge [bend left]        node {aabc}  (F)
            edge [swap, bend right] node {c}     (F)
        (r) edge                    node {aabc}  (F)
            edge [swap, bend right] node {c}     (F);   
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: `\draw[->] (I) -- ++(0,-3) -| (F) node[below,pos=0.25] {c};` (you might need to adjust the `-3` part to clear all the edges).

Comment: Certainly. See for example [How to draw a return arrow from node-3 to node-1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102385) -- [Tikz: two edges path connection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252241)  -- [Is there a TikZ equivalent to the PSTricks \ncbar command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068) -- [Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45347) and there are probably others around as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw a return arrow from node-3 to node-1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102385/how-to-draw-a-return-arrow-from-node-3-to-node-1)

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/vertical-and-horizontal-lines-in-pgf-tikz

Comment: @PaulGessler I would accept one of the answers, but your comment is the only solution that worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

[image]

This is simple. Nodes in automaton are as other nodes in tikzpictures, so you can draw lines between them as you wish. In this case with help `|-` , `yshift` and `-|` between nodes I, r and F:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,node distance=2.7cm,auto]
    \node[state,initial,accepting]  (I)                      {$I$};
    \node[state]                    (p) [above right of = I] {$p$};
    \node[state]                    (q) [right of = p]       {$q$};
    \node[state]                    (r) [below right of = I] {$r$};
    \node[state,accepting]          (F) [below right of = q] {$F$};

    \path[->]
        (I) edge                    node {a} (p)
            edge                    node {b}     (r)
        (p) edge                    node {b}     (q)
            edge [swap, bend right] node {abc}   (F)
        (q) edge [bend left]        node {aabc}  (F)
            edge [swap, bend right] node {c}     (F)
        (r) edge                    node {aabc}  (F)
            edge [swap, bend right] node {c}     (F);
\draw[red,thick,->] (I) |- ([yshift=-5mm] r.south) -| (F);% <-- added
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zarko's solution is fine is good but I prefried a solution that automatically calculates the correct placement
this solution use fit library

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,node distance=2.7cm,auto]
    \node[state,initial,accepting]  (I)                      {$I$};
    \node[state]                    (p) [above right of = I] {$p$};
    \node[state]                    (q) [right of = p]       {$q$};
    \node[state]                    (r) [below right of = I] {$r$};
    \node[state,accepting]          (F) [below right of = q] {$F$};

    \path[->]
        (I) edge                    node {a} (p)
            edge                    node {b}     (r)
        (p) edge                    node {b}     (q)
            edge [swap, bend right] node {abc}   (F)
        (q) edge [bend left]        node {aabc}  (F)
            edge [swap, bend right] node {c}     (F)
        (r) edge                    node {aabc}  (F)
            edge [swap, bend right] node {c}     (F);


\node[fit=(p) (r) (q) (F) (I)](all){};
\draw[red] (F) |-(all.south) -| (I);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image]