# Flow Chart with tikzpicture: particular types of arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I have this code:

```
    % Define block styles
      \tikzstyle{C} = [diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em, text     badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
      \tikzstyle{I} = [chamfered rectangle, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, draw,chamfered rectangle corners=north west]
      \tikzstyle{P} = [chamfered rectangle, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, draw,chamfered rectangle corners=south east] 
      \tikzstyle{V} = [rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm]   
      \tikzstyle{S} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!70, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em]
      \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
      %------------------------------------------------
     \begin{center}
     \begin{tikzpicture}
      %nodes
     \node [S] (S1) {\textbf{START}};
     \node [I, below of=S1,node distance=1.5cm] (I1) {$ x $};
     \node [I, below of=I1,node distance=1.5cm] (I2) {$ n $};
     \node [C, below of=I2,node distance=2.1cm] (C1) {$ n\>0 $};
     \node [V, below of=C1,node distance=2.1cm] (V1) {$ i\leftarrow 1 $};
     \node [C, below of=V1,node distance=2.1cm] (C2) {$ i\<n $};
     \node [S, right of=C2,node distance=2.7cm] (S2) {\textbf{STOP}};
     \node [V, below of=C2,node distance=2.1cm] (V2) {$ y=x+i $};
     \node [P, below of=V2,node distance=1.5cm] (P1) {$ y $};
     \node [V, below of=P1,node distance=1.5cm] (V3) {$ i\leftarrow i+1 $};
     %arrows
     \begin{scope} [every path/.style=line]
     \path  (S1) -- (I1);
     \path  (I1) -- (I2);
     \path  (I2) -- (C1);
     \path  (C1) -- (V1);  
     \path  (V1) -- (C2);
     \path  (C2) -- (V2);  \path  (C2) -- (S2);
     \path  (V2) -- (P1);  
     \path  (P1) -- (V3);   
     \end{scope}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{center}
```

and I have this output:

[image]

How to get instead the output:

[image]

In other words, which kind of command I need in order to get the arrows in blue?

Comment: please help us to help you! transform your code sniped to complete document starting with `\documentclass{...}` used libraries and packages, `begin{document}` your flowchart `\end}doument}`.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55068 and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative solution, which exploit `chains` library features.

**Edit:**
In case, that you like to have some lines determined by `join` option, the first solution is extended with new `join` line type and style, which enable its use

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=5mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, chains, positioning, shapes, shapes.misc}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{suppress join/.code={\def\tikz@after@path{}}}
\makeatother

%------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
     \begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance=5 mm and 7mm,
     start chain = going below,
base/.style = {draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm, 
               align=center, on chain, join=by ->},
   C/.style = {base, diamond, fill=blue!20, inner sep=0pt}, 
   I/.style = {base, chamfered rectangle,  
               chamfered rectangle corners=north west},
   P/.style = {base,chamfered rectangle, draw,chamfered rectangle corners=south east},
   V/.style = {base, rectangle},
   S/.style = {base, ellipse, fill=red!70},
line/.style = {-latex'}
  dl/.style = {-latex', dashed},          % <-- added for dashed "join" lines
 jdl/.style = {suppress join, join= by dl}% <-- enable dashed "join" lines
                        ]
      %nodes
\node [S] (S1) {\textbf{START}};
\node [I] (I1) {$ x $};
\node [I] (I2) {$ n $};
\node [C] (C1) {$ n\geq 0 $};
\node [V] (V1) {$ i\leftarrow 1 $};
\node [C] (C2) {$ i\leq n $};
\node [V] (V2) {$ y=x+i $};
\node [P] (P1) {$ y $};
\node [V,jdl]  % <-- this node is connected with previous by dashed arrow
          (V3) {$ i\leftarrow i+1 $};
%
\node [S, suppress join, right=of C2] (S2) {\textbf{STOP}};
     %arrows
\draw[dl]    (V3.west) -- + (-1,0) |- (C2);% <-- solved OP problem
\draw[line]  (C1.east) -- + ( 1,0) |- (I2) % <-- solved OP problem
             (C2) edge (S2);
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In MWE is used correct positioning syntax and node styles definitions. Drawing vertical lines are left to `join` macro.

Comment: Your graph differs from the OP's one: One of the new arrows is wrong, and `><` should be `\geq\leq`.

Comment: fixed! actually OP here have errors in code ...

Comment: Hard to tell whether it's an error. Maybe there is a package that defines `\>` and  `\<` in a suitable way; the OP doesn't show the preamble.

Comment: One arrow is still wrong: It should not emerge at the STOP node but at the first branch.

Comment: After recent revision of my answer I unified arrows style (your definition I simplify to `line/.style = {-latex'}` and move to option of `tikzpicture`). It is used for style of join lines as well as for drawing other lines.

Comment: @Zarko Thank you so much! Chains are very nice!

Comment: @Zarko there is a way in order to get just one arrow in chain dashed?

Comment: which one? if is part of `join` is not so simple. You need suppress `join` and write this line separately. If it is one of back loop lines, just add `dashed` to `\draw` option, for example `\draw[line,dashed]  (V3.west) -- + (-1,0) |- (C2);`

Comment: @Zarko It works. Thank you. There is a way in order to obtain a dashed arrow just putting 'dashed' instead of suppress join?

Comment: In edit of my answer. In it  I add option how to make some `join` arrows (lines) dashed.

Answer (score 3):

Define four auxiliary nodes:

```
\node [coordinate, right of=I2, node distance=2cm] (I2r) {};
\node [coordinate, right of=C1, node distance=2cm] (C1r) {};
\node [coordinate, left of=C2, node distance=2cm] (C2l) {};
\node [coordinate, left of=V3, node distance=2cm] (V3l) {};
```

Then you can draw the missing arrows by adding these path commands to the `scope` environment:

```
\path  (C1) -- (C1r) -- (I2r) -- (I2);
\path  (V3) -- (V3l) -- (C2l) -- (C2);
```

Do the commands `\<` and `\>` really work in your context? I have to use `\leq` and `\geq` instead.

Here is the complete code and its output.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset
  {C/.style={diamond, draw, fill=blue!20, text width=4.5em,
             text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt
            },
   I/.style={chamfered rectangle, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm,
             draw,chamfered rectangle corners=north west
            },
   P/.style={chamfered rectangle, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm,
             draw,chamfered rectangle corners=south east
            },
   V/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1cm},
   S/.style={draw, ellipse,fill=red!70, node distance=3cm, minimum height=2em},
   line/.style={draw, -latex'}
  }
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [S] (S1) {\textbf{START}};
  \node [I, below of=S1,node distance=1.5cm] (I1) {$ x $};
  \node [I, below of=I1,node distance=1.5cm] (I2) {$ n $};
  \node [C, below of=I2,node distance=2.1cm] (C1) {$ n\geq 0 $};
  \node [V, below of=C1,node distance=2.1cm] (V1) {$ i\leftarrow 1 $};
  \node [C, below of=V1,node distance=2.1cm] (C2) {$ i\leq n $};
  \node [S, right of=C2,node distance=2.7cm] (S2) {\textbf{STOP}};
  \node [V, below of=C2,node distance=2.1cm] (V2) {$ y=x+i $};
  \node [P, below of=V2,node distance=1.5cm] (P1) {$ y $};
  \node [V, below of=P1,node distance=1.5cm] (V3) {$ i\leftarrow i+1 $};
  \node [coordinate, right of=I2, node distance=2cm] (I2r) {};
  \node [coordinate, right of=C1, node distance=2cm] (C1r) {};
  \node [coordinate, left of=C2, node distance=2cm] (C2l) {};
  \node [coordinate, left of=V3, node distance=2cm] (V3l) {};
  \begin{scope} [every path/.style=line]
    \path  (S1) -- (I1);
    \path  (I1) -- (I2);
    \path  (I2) -- (C1);
    \path  (C1) -- (V1);  
    \path  (V1) -- (C2);
    \path  (C2) -- (V2);
    \path  (C2) -- (S2);
    \path  (V2) -- (P1);  
    \path  (P1) -- (V3);   
    \path  (C1) -- (C1r) -- (I2r) -- (I2);
    \path  (V3) -- (V3l) -- (C2l) -- (C2);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]