# Movement arrows in gloss not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, gb4e

I would like to be able to draw movement arrows (which can overlap) underneath a linguistic example sentence (not a tree).  However, everyone seems to be using gb4e but when I paste the examples into TexShop and compile them the arrows come out a weird angles and the text is messed up..(see screenshots).. Any idea what is going on? [image: scrambled movement arrow] [image: messed up text]  Thanks in advance.

The code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, dvipdfmx]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)] \node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (#1) {#1};}

% This code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068/2693
\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
    ncbar/.style={
        to path=(\tikztostart)
        -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
        -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
        -- (\tikztotarget)
    },
    ncbar/.default=0.5cm,
}

% Thanks to Paul Gessler adn Percusse for code improvement here
\newcommand{\arrow}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt] (#1.base) to [ncbar=\arrowht] (#2.base);
\end{tikzpicture}
\setlength{\arrowht}{0ex}
}
\usepackage{gb4e}
% The following code modified from 
% http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.linguistics/1036
% This adds some extra space after the first line
\newlength{\arrowht}
\setlength{\arrowht}{0ex}
\newcommand*\cgdepthstrut{{\vrule height 0pt depth \arrowht width 0pt}}
\renewcommand\eachwordone{\cgdepthstrut\rmfamily}
\renewcommand\glt{\vskip -\topsep}
\let\trans=\glt
\newcommand\arrowex{\setlength{\arrowht}{2.5ex}\ex}


\begin{document}
\begin{exe}
\ex\label{scramble-det}
\begin{xlist}
        \arrowex 
        \gll 
        \ldots dat Jan \tikzmark{een} auto gisteren \tikzmark{t}  gekregen heeft.\\
        \ldots that John a car  yesterday t gotten has \\
        \ldots that John a car yesterday.
        \arrow{t}{een}
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\ex\label{scramble-dets}
\begin{xlist}
        \ex 
        \gll 
        \ldots dat Jan een auto gisteren t gekregen heeft.\\
        \ldots that John a car  yesterday t gotten has \\
        \ldots that John a car yesterday.
\end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\begin{exe}
\ex[]{
    \gll
    John-wa totetumonaiukurai baka-da.    \\
    John-Top very stupid-cop \\
    `John is very studip.'    
}

\ex[]{
    \gll
    John-wa totetumonaiukurai dousiyoumonai tondemonai sukuigatai baka-da.    \\
    John-Top very very very very stupid-cop \\
    `John is very studip.'    
}

\arrowex[]{
    \gll
    \tikzmark{John}-wa totetumonaiukurai dousiyoumonai tondemonai sukuigatai  \tikzmark{t} baka-da.    \\
    John-Top very very very very stupid-cop \\
    `John is very stupid.'    
    \arrow{t}{John}
}

\end{exe}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `dvipdfmx` to the document class? And you can't draw an arrow automatically from the second line of a gloss to the first. But this is a duplicate of [Long-distance movement arrow in gloss](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/380954).