# alignment between an example in gb4e and the bracketed gloss

Tags: arrows, linguistics, gb4e

I need to have the words on the first line not so wide apart as in ex. 1 (ovaj and zadatak) and ex. 3 (je and vazan). Also, if possible, I'd like to have the bracketed second line more aligned with the first line. Any suggestions? Thank you for any suggestions. Here's the code that I have borrowed:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\newlength{\arrowht}
\setlength{\arrowht}{-2.5ex}% <-- changed
\newcommand*\exdepthstrut{{\vrule height 0.75\arrowht depth    
-0.25\arrowht width 0pt}}% <-- changed
\newcommand\tikzmark[1]{\tikz[remember picture, baseline=(#1.base)]     
\node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt] (#1)  
{#1\exdepthstrut};}
% This code from http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55068/2693

\tikzset{
    ncbar angle/.initial=90,
ncbar/.style={
    to path=(\tikztostart)
    -- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)
    -- ($(\tikztotarget)!($(\tikztostart)!#1!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztotarget)$)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ncbar angle}:(\tikztostart)$)
    -- (\tikztotarget)
},
ncbar/.default=\arrowht,% <-- changed
}
% Thanks to Paul Gessler and Percusse for code improvement here
\newcommand{\arrow}[2]{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[->,shorten >=1ex,shorten <=1ex] ([yshift=1.25ex] #1.south) to   
 [ncbar] ([yshift=1.25ex] #2.south);% <-- changed
\end{tikzpicture}
}

  \begin{itemize}
   \item Merger of Be:
     \end{itemize}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{exe}
       \ex Complex predicate formation
        \gll ~\tikzmark{vazan} ~be   ovaj zadatak veoma \tikzmark{t}\\
            ~[BeP [PredP $t_i${important$_i$}]][Be][ KP {this task$_i$} 
[PredP {very} [Pred {$t_i$} ]]]] ]\\
            \arrow{t}{vazan}

            \begin{itemize}
               \item Merger of T:
            \end{itemize}

          \ex Be to T
       \gll  ~\tikzmark{je} vazan \tikzmark{t} ovaj zadatak veoma t t\\
         ~[T [Be {is$_k$} [T]] [BeP {[PredP$_j$ {$t_i$} {important$_j$}   
   ]} [Be t_k ] [ KP {this task$_i$} [PredP {very} $t_j$ ]]]]\\
           \arrow{t}{je}
        \begin{itemize}
           \item merger of TP
       \end{itemize}

         \ex Predicate inversion
         \gll  ~\tikzmark{Veoma} je vazan t ovaj zadatak \tikzmark{t} t      
 t\\
        ~[TP [PredP$_l$ {very} $t_j$ ][T [Be {is$_k$} [T]] [BeP   
   {[PredP$_j$ {$t_i$} {important$_j$} ]} [Be t_k ] [ KP {this   
task$_i$}    
    $t_l$]]]]]\\
        \arrow{t}{Veoma}
   \end{exe}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you upload an image of what you want the output to look like, showing how the lines should be aligned? In general, you need the same number of space-separated terms/words in each gloss line, using `{}` as needed to group elements that should be considered a single term/word.

Comment: Instead of `~`, I recommend using `\phantom{}` with the actual symbol that appears in the other gloss line. You could define your own shortcut/alias of that command if you find it to be too cumbersome to type.

Comment: And for words/terms in one line where the corresponding line should be blank, use `{}` as needed for the blank words/terms.