# How to connect nodes with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-chains

I hope you help me.
I want to connect these nodes as in the attached image. I tried it using chains, but I could'n get it. I'd like to use the best way to connect nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{New}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

 \draw (6,3) node (problema) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=50mm]{\small{\center \textbf{TITLE}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};

 \draw (0,0) node (causa1) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=40mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};
 \draw (6,0) node (causa2) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=40mm]{\small{ \textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};
 \draw (12,0) node (causa3) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=40mm]{\small{ \textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};

\draw (problema) -| (causa1);
\draw (problema) -- (causa2);
\draw (problema) -| (causa3);

 \draw (0,-2.2) node (indir1) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=30mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};
 \draw (0,-4.4) node (indir2) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=30mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};
 \draw (0,-6.6) node (indir3) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=30mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};
 \draw (0,-8.8) node (indir4) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=30mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};

 \draw (6,-2.2) node (indir5) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=30mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};
 \draw (6,-4.4) node (indir6) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=30mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};
 \draw (6,-6.6) node (indir7) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=30mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};
 \draw (6,-8.8) node (indir8) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=30mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};
 \draw (6,-11) node (indir9) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=30mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};

 \draw (12,-2.2) node (indir10) [draw,rounded corners,align=left,text width=30mm]{\small{\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use relative coordinates for this. An example for the top can be:

```
\draw (problema) -- ++(0, -10pt) -| (causa1);
```

Similar for the rest. Move the line a bit then use the straight-angled link.

Comment: For the rest I used:    `\draw (causa1.west)--++(-10mm,0mm)--++(0mm,-2.2)--(indir1.west);`; Thanks

Comment: No problem. You should really use the `-|` or `|-` for the final two lines though. It makes life very easy.

Comment: You're right, for the line of my comment, `|-` instead of `--++(0mm,-2.2)--`

Comment: @Isai, how to put a label using `|-` above the segment?

Answer (score 6):

You can use chains for this! And even better we can automatically draw the lines with the `join` option.

But first things first: Please use styles. And please use the `positioning` library (loaded by the `chains` library) to place the nodes instead of hard-coding the coordinates. The `positioning` library makes it more intuitive to place nodes and also makes sure, that the nodes do not overlap.

I used my `paths.ortho` library and its path operator `lr` and `rl`. The library itself comes from [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102409/16595) to [How to draw a return arrow from node-3 to node-1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102385/16595) (but don’t use that code from that answer) and is further explained in [another answer of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/16595).

Without the `paths.ortho` library, the `place nodes on chain and install special path` style’s definition would be

```
place nodes on chain and install special path/.style n args={3}{
  every node/.append style={on chain=#1,join},
  every join/.append style={to path=(#1-begin.#3) #2 (\tikztotarget)}
}
```

which can then be used as

```
place nodes on chain and install special path={ch1}{-- ++(left:.5cm) |-}{west}
place nodes on chain and install special path={ch2}{-- ++(left:.5cm) |-}{west}
```

and

```
place nodes on chain and install special path={ch}{-- ++(right:.5cm) |-}{east}
```

while having the same output.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,paths.ortho}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  ultra thick,
  node distance=1cm and 2cm,
  every node/.append style={
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    align=left,
    font=\small
  },
  top node/.style={text width=+55mm},
  wide node/.style={text width=+40mm},
  thin node/.style={text width=+30mm},
  start chain/.list={ch1 going below, ch2 going below, ch3 going below}
]

\node[top node](problema) {\textbf{TITLE}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};

\begin{scope}[every node/.append style={wide node}]
  \node[below=of problema, on chain=ch2] (causa2) {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
  \node[left=of causa2   , on chain=ch1] (causa1) {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
  \node[right=of causa2  , on chain=ch3] (causa3) {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[
  every node/.append style={thin node},
  place nodes on chain and install special path/.style 2 args={
    every node/.append style={on chain=#1,join},every join/.append style={to path=(#1-begin) #2 (\tikztotarget)}
  }
]
  \begin{scope}[place nodes on chain and install special path={ch1}{lr}]
    \node {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[place nodes on chain and install special path={ch2}{lr}]
    \node {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
    \node {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[place nodes on chain and install special path={ch3}{rl}]
    \node {\textbf{Title}\\ Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text};
  \end{scope}
\end{scope}

\draw (problema) -| (causa1);
\draw (problema) -- (causa2);
\draw (problema) -| (causa3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]