# Draw arrows between nodes with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have drawn 4 nodes with

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

% nodes
\node [draw] (A) {A};
\node [draw, right=of A] (B) {B};
\node [draw, right=of B] (C) {C};
\node [draw, right=of C] (D) {D};

% arrows
\draw [->] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to draw an arrow between each node.

If I use

```
\draw [->] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D);
```

I get lines between each node but only an arrow from C to D.

Can I, in one line, draw arrows between all of the nodes?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`edge` can be used to put the arrows in one `\draw` command:

```
\draw [->] (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C) (C) edge (D);
```

The usage of `-|` as path for `edge` is also possible via option `to path`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

% nodes
\node (A) at (0, 0) {A};
\node (B) at (1, 1) {B};
\node (C) at (2, 1.5) {C};
\node (D) at (3, 0) {D};

% arrows
\draw[->, to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}]
  (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C) (C) edge (D);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @Raphael Yes, see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you! (Nota bene: more complicated paths can be given, but then nodes specified like `edge[...] node {...} (target)` won't appear.)

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, how to add names to edge? For example `(A) edge node[pos=0.75,right] {a} (B)` doesn't show node `a`.

Comment: @Zarko The edges are set at a later time, thus `node` does not see the path of the edge. A workaround is to add the node to a non-drawn path: `\path (A) -| node[pos=0.75,right] {a} (B);`

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, yes, on such a way this works, however, with your solution `\draw[->, to path={-| (\tikztotarget)}] ....` this is not possible anymore (because `edge target`  is already incorporated into edge, I think so). Meanwhile i figured out an complicated solution ... if you interested, how I do this, see my upgrade of my answer on question  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273928/orthogonal-edges-style. And, thank you very much!