# TikZ: How to accurately calculate the distance between nodes anchors? - Effect of outer separation on anchors location

Tags: tikz-pgf

In this code, I configured the `text width=2cm` and `inner sep=0cm` with horizontal node separation of `1cm`. Therefore, I should assume that the horizontal distance between `start.north` and `end.north` is `2*0.5 + 1 + 2*0.5 = 3cm`.

However, in the first example, I entered a horizontal shift of `3cm` for the line segment which doesn't 100% accurately align with `end.north`. You can notice this little deviation from the output of the second example using the simple command `-|`.

Did I misunderstand or miss something?

---

**Edit**

---

In [pgfmanual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), under `outer sep`, there is a statement

> This option adds an additional (invisible) separation space of hdimensioni outside the background path.
>   The main effect of this option is that all anchors will move a little “to the outside.”

So, if both anchors `start.north` and `end.north` are shifted by the same amount, why would I need to add an additional `\pgflinewidth` to the horizontal `3cm` segment according to the comments?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.geometric,calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',very thick,align=center]

        \tikzset{%
        block/.style= {draw, rectangle, text width=2cm,inner sep=0cm,minimum height=1cm,node distance=2cm and 1cm}
        }

        \node [block]  (start1) {Start1};
        \node [block, right = of start1] (end1) {End1};
        \node [block, below = of start1] (start2) {Start2};
        \node [block, right = of start2] (end2) {End2};

        \path[draw,->] 
        (start1.north) -- ++(0,1cm) -- ++(3cm,0) -- (end1.north);

        \path[draw,->] 
        (start2.north) -- ++(0,1cm) -| (end2.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You have to consider also `line width`. Try `++(3cm+\pgflinewidth,0)`

Comment: Many thanks, you are right. I would be grateful if you put a complete answer with a brief explanation to be comprehensive and informative for anyone including me.

Comment: Actually, it is twice the `outer xsep`s (by default set to `.5\linewidth`). You might also want to do `(start.north) --++(up:1cm) -- ([shift=(up:1cm)] end.north) -- (end)` if you can't use `-|` or similar.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thanks, but could you provide a comprehensive answer below since I am quite new to TikZ and not familiar with the meaning of `outer xsep`.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Interesting. I didn't know you could use `up` like that.

Comment: You're not taking account of the fact that the distance between the nodes is measured as it would be between the relevant node anchors, I think i.e. on the outer boundary east and west. So you have an additional `outer sep` twice.

Comment: @cfr I am sorry, but what does `outer sep` do actually for both `start.north` and `end.north`? I think `outer sep` pushes them horizontally the same distance. What is missing in my understanding to consider `\pgflinewidth` for those north anchors in that horizontal offset?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this kind of case, it is easier to visualise things if you exaggerate the relevant dimensions. In this case, a large `line width` (and, hence, a large `outer sep`) may help:

[image: visualising with an exaggerated dimension]

*w1* and *w2* are the `text width`s of the nodes.

Adding your arrow from the top of the first to the top of the second node, the problem should be clear:

[image: problem]

That is, the problem [Qrrbrbirlbel pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/314473/tikz-how-to-accurately-calculate-the-distance-between-nodes-anchors-effect-o#comment767109_314473) is not a regular displacement of each anchor by a standard amount - such a pattern would, as you say, not affect the arrow which uses only relative coordinates. Rather, it is that the default `outer sep` of each node pushes the anchors further apart because the distance between the nodes is measured from the outer borders of those nodes and not from the centre of the line drawn around them.

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,positioning,quotes,backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\newlength\nd
\setlength\nd{30mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    every edge quotes/.style={fill=white, inner sep=1pt, font=\footnotesize, text=red, midway},
    grey node/.style={draw=gray!50, line width=5mm, draw opacity=.5, inner sep=0pt, minimum height=20mm, text centered},
    red line/.style={ultra thin, draw=red},
    red dim/.style={>={Stealth[fill=red]}, <->},
    red mini dim/.style={>={Stealth[fill=red, scale=.5]}, <->},
    red anchor/.style={draw=red, ultra thin, fill=white},
    grey arrows/.style={help lines, -{Stealth[]}},
  ]
  \coordinate (o);
  \foreach \j/\k [count=\no, remember=\j as \lastj, remember=\k as \lastk] in {n/40,m/30}
  {
    \ifnum\no=1
      \node (\j) [grey node, text width=\k mm] {Node \no};
    \else
      \node (\j) [grey node, right=\nd of \lastj, text width=\k mm] {Node \no};
    \fi
    \path [red line] (\j.north west) rectangle (\j.south east) ([xshift=-.5*\k mm, yshift=10mm]\j.center)  -| ++(\k mm,-5mm) edge [red dim, "$w_\no$"]  ++(-\k mm,0) -- ++(0,-15mm) -| cycle;
    \foreach \i in {north, south, east, west, north east, north west, south east, south west} \path [red anchor] (\j.\i) circle (.5mm);
    \ifnum\no=1
      \relax
    \else
      \path [red line] ([yshift=-5mm]\lastj.east) edge ["node distance", red dim] ++(\nd,0);
      \path [red line] ([yshift=-10mm]\lastj.east) edge [draw=none, every edge quotes/.append style={name=s}, "outer sep", red dim] ++(\nd,0);
      \path [draw, -Stealth, shorten <=.5mm, shorten >=.5mm] (\lastj.north) -- ++(0,10mm) -- ++(.5*\lastk mm,0) -- ++(\nd,0) -- ++(.5*\k mm,0) -- (\j.north);
    \fi
  }
  \path [red line, red mini dim] ([yshift=-7.5mm]n.east) -- ++(-2.5mm,0) coordinate [midway] (n1) coordinate (n2);
  \path [red line, red mini dim] ([yshift=-7.5mm]m.west) -- ++(2.5mm,0) coordinate [midway] (m1) coordinate (m2);
  \draw [grey arrows] (s) -| (m1);
  \draw [grey arrows] (s) -| (n1);
  \begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \coordinate (p) at ([yshift=5mm]current bounding box.north);
    \coordinate (g) at ([yshift=-5mm]current bounding box.south);
    \foreach \i in {n.center,m.center,m2,n2,n.east,m.west} \draw [blue!50!cyan!75!gray, ultra thin, densely dashed] (\i |- p) -- (\i |- g);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the second time in a row, you gave me a solid informative answer with comprehensive explanation. I am highly appreciative of your time and effort you dedicated to this answer. Not all heroes wear capes :)

Comment: Well it is just what Qrrbrbirlbel said but with pictures, really.

Comment: I know right, but graphic illustration made me figure it out and removed my confusion, and it took you time and effort which I have to appreciate and be grateful for.