# Any easier way to draw lots of arrows in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I draw lots of block diagrams like this one (source below):

[image]

The arrow drawing contains a lot of repetitive `\draw[->]` commands, and I'm wondering: is there any way to create a shortcut so that this

```
\draw[->] (x) -- (sum6);
\draw[->] (sum6) -- (K0);
\draw[->] (dot5) -- (Kp);
\draw[->] (dot5) |- (Ki);
\draw[->] (Kp) -- (sum7);
\draw[->] (Ki) -- (int3);
\draw[->] (int3) -- (dot4) -- (sum7);
\draw[->] (sum7) -- (int2);
\draw[->] (int2) -- (sum6);
\draw[->] (dot4) -- (w_e);
\draw[-] (K0) -| ++(12mm,-12mm) -| (dot5);
```

could be replaced with this (arrowheads inline rather than in each `\draw` command option):

```
\draw[arrowcontext]
     (x) --> (sum6) --> (K0) -| ++(12mm,-12mm) -| (dot5)
         --> (Kp) --> (sum7) --> (int2) --> (sum6)
     (dot5) |-> (Ki) --> (int3) -- (dot4) --> (sum7) 
     (dot4) --> (w_e);
```

full source:

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto,
       blockcolors/.style={
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black!10,
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    blockheight/.style = {
        minimum height=10mm
    },
    block/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=12mm,
        blockheight,
        node distance=5mm,
        blockcolors,
        drop shadow
    },
    phantom/.style={
    },
    open circle/.style={
        circle, inner sep=0pt,
        thick,draw=black,
        fill = white,
    },
    input/.style={open circle, minimum size=2mm, node distance=8mm, fill=green!70!black},
    output/.style={input},
    junction/.style={open circle, minimum size=0.5mm,fill=black, node distance=5mm},
    sum/.style={open circle, minimum size=4mm, node distance=8mm},
       gain/.style={
          draw,
          shape border rotate=-90,
          inner sep=0.5mm,
          regular polygon,
          regular polygon sides=3,
          blockcolors, drop shadow
       },   
    every label/.style={
        font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },
    >=latex
    ]
\def\NEAR{4.0mm of }
\node (x) [input, label={[font=\normalsize]$x$}] {};
\node (sum6) [sum, below=of x] {};
\node (K0) [gain, inner sep=0mm, right=6mm of sum6]{$K_0$};
\node (int2) [block, left=7mm of sum6]{$\medint\int dt$};
\node (sum7) [sum, left=\NEAR int2] {};
\node (dot4) [junction] at (x -| sum7){};

\node (int3) [block, left=of dot4]{$\medint\int dt$};
\node (Ki) [gain, left=of int3, inner sep=-0.4mm] {$K_I$};
\node (Kp) [gain, inner sep=-0.65mm] at (Ki |- sum7){$K_P$};
\node (dot5) [junction, left=of Kp]{};
\node (w_e) [output, right=of dot4, label={[font=\normalsize]above:$\hat{\omega}_e$}]{};

\draw[->] (x) -- (sum6);
\draw[->] (sum6) -- (K0);
\draw[->] (dot5) -- (Kp);
\draw[->] (dot5) |- (Ki);
\draw[->] (Kp) -- (sum7);
\draw[->] (Ki) -- (int3);
\draw[->] (int3) -- (dot4) -- (sum7);
\draw[->] (sum7) -- (int2);
\draw[->] (int2) -- (sum6);
\draw[->] (dot4) -- (w_e);
\draw[-] (K0) -| ++(12mm,-12mm) -| (dot5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: instead of `-->` use `to`

Comment: interesting... is there a way to handle the `|->` and `-|>` cases?

Comment: but @percusse, `--` and `to` seem to have the same effect, they don't give me multiple arrows for a given `\draw[->]` command

Comment: have you actually thought about using the `chains` library of tikz? That way you could avoid most of the draw commans alltogether as longs as all the elements are connected to a chain.

Comment: See also [Draw arrows between nodes with tikz - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251642/draw-arrows-between-nodes-with-tikz)

Answer (score 6):

Some options:

### `edge`

```
\draw[->]
  (x) edge (sum6)
  (sum6) edge (K0)
  % ...
;
```

### `\foreach`

```
\foreach \a/\b in {
   x/sum6,
   sum6/K0,
   % ...
} \draw[->] (\a) -- (\b);
```

### `scope`

At least, the common option can be set in environment `scope`:

```
\begin{scope}[->]
  \draw (x) -- (sum6);
  \draw (sum6) -- (K0);
  % ...
\end{scope}
```

Comment: the `foreach` case is interesting but doesn't work for me, the diagrams are too irregular (and I often have `node[above]{some_label_text}` interspersed). The `edge` case is helpful... how do you handle the `|-` corners though?

Comment: @JasonS AFAIK, arbitrary paths are not possible with `edge`.

Comment: @JasonS What @HeikoOberdiek is saying about `-|` is not completely true. You can define a style `\tikzset{-|/.style={to path={(\tikztostart) -| (\tikztotarget)}}}` and then use it like this `(a) edge[-|] (b)`.

Answer (score 3):

As it has been suggested `chains` library could be an option. Information about this library can be found in section [46 Chains](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/pgf#page=541) from `TikZ` documentation.

The main advantage is that for each element on a `chain` a `join` definition can be defined, so just `chaining` elements, all joins are drawn.

In following code, a `matrix of nodes` has been used to place all the elements and, later on, they have been added to two chains, on for the upper row and a second for the lower one.

Vertical joins and feedback join have been drawn with individual commands.

`scopes` library has been used to type `{[start chain]...}` instead of `\begin{scope}[start chain]...\end{scope}`.

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,shadows,arrows, matrix, chains, scopes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto,
       blockcolors/.style={
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black!10,
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    blockheight/.style = {
        minimum height=10mm
    },
    block/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=12mm,
        blockheight,
        node distance=5mm,
        blockcolors,
        drop shadow
    },
    phantom/.style={
    },
    open circle/.style={
        circle, inner sep=0pt,
        thick,draw=black,
        fill = white,
    },
    input/.style={open circle, minimum size=2mm, node distance=8mm, fill=green!70!black},
    output/.style={input},
    junction/.style={open circle, minimum size=0.5mm,fill=black, node distance=5mm},
    sum/.style={open circle, minimum size=4mm, node distance=8mm},
       gain/.style={
          draw,
          shape border rotate=-90,
          inner sep=0.5mm,
          regular polygon,
          regular polygon sides=3,
          blockcolors, drop shadow
       },   
    every label/.style={
        font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },
    >=latex,
    every on chain/.style=join, 
    every join/.style={->},
    ]

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, row sep=1mm, column sep=5mm, nodes={anchor=center}]
{
%first row
    & |[gain, inner sep=-.4mm]|$K_I$ 
    & |[block]| $\medint\int dt$ 
    & |[junction]| 
    & |[input,  label={[font=\normalsize]above:$\hat{\omega}_e$}]| 
    & |[input,  label={[font=\normalsize]above:$x$}]|\\
%second row
      |[junction]| 
    & |[gain, inner sep=-.65mm]|$K_P$ 
    & 
    & |[sum]| 
    & |[block]| $\medint\int dt$ 
    & |[sum]| 
    & |[gain, inner sep=0pt]| $K_0$ \\
};

{[start chain]
    \chainin (A-2-1);
    \chainin (A-2-2);
    \chainin (A-2-4);
    \chainin (A-2-5);
    \chainin (A-2-6);
    \chainin (A-2-7);
}

{[start chain]
    \chainin (A-1-2);
    \chainin (A-1-3);
    \chainin (A-1-5);
}

\draw[->] (A-1-4)--(A-2-4);
\draw[->] (A-1-6)--(A-2-6);
\draw[->] (A-2-7)--++(0:1cm)--++(-90:1cm)-|(A-2-1)|-(A-1-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2nd Version: `\graph`**

An alternative to `chains` library could be `graphs` library. Although `graphs` offers a lot of possibilities which implies using `LuaLaTeX`, this simple example will work with `pdfLaTeX`.

At the moment of writing this answer I don't know how to solve what seems to be an incompatibility between node's names with hyphens (i.e. A-1-1) and `\graph` command (see: [`graph` command doesn't accept nodes named with `-`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331731/graph-command-doesnt-accept-nodes-named-with?noredirect=1#comment812946_331731)). So, I've introduced syntax `(namewithouthyphen)` in every matrix node to allow using `graph` command.

Instead of just

```
    & |[gain, inner sep=-.4mm]|$K_I$
```

every node has been preceded by a name declaration:

```
    & |(A12)[gain, inner sep=-.4mm]|$K_I$
```

Another valid syntax could be `|[name=A12, gain, inner sep=-.4mm]|`

`\graph` command accepts some already defined edges between nodes, but it's possible to define new ones. In this case, `feedback` and `cornerupright` have been defined as following `to path`:

```
feedback/.style={to path={--++(0:1cm)--++(-90:1cm)-|(\tikztotarget)}},
cornerupright/.style={to path={|-(\tikztotarget)}},
```

With all these changes, all connections except two can be defined within a unique line:

```
\graph[use existing nodes]{%
A21->A22->A24->A25->A26->A27--[feedback]A21->[cornerupright]A12->A13->A15;
A14->A24;
A16->A26;
};
```

The result is exactly the same obtained with `chains` library.

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass[border=6mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, shadows, arrows, matrix, graphs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm, auto,
       blockcolors/.style={
        % The rest
        thick,draw=black,
        top color=white,
        bottom color=black!10,
        font=\sffamily\small
    },
    blockheight/.style = {
        minimum height=10mm
    },
    block/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle, minimum size=6mm, minimum width=12mm,
        blockheight,
        node distance=5mm,
        blockcolors,
        drop shadow
    },
    phantom/.style={
    },
    open circle/.style={
        circle, inner sep=0pt,
        thick,draw=black,
        fill = white,
    },
    input/.style={open circle, minimum size=2mm, node distance=8mm, fill=green!70!black},
    output/.style={input},
    junction/.style={open circle, minimum size=0.5mm,fill=black, node distance=5mm},
    sum/.style={open circle, minimum size=4mm, node distance=8mm},
       gain/.style={
          draw,
          shape border rotate=-90,
          inner sep=0.5mm,
          regular polygon,
          regular polygon sides=3,
          blockcolors, drop shadow
       },   
    every label/.style={
        font=\sffamily\scriptsize
    },
    >=latex,
    feedback/.style={to path={--++(0:1cm)--++(-90:1cm)-|(\tikztotarget)}},
    cornerupright/.style={to path={|-(\tikztotarget)}},
    ]

\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes, row sep=1mm, column sep=5mm, nodes={anchor=center}]
{
%first row
    & |(A12)[gain, inner sep=-.4mm]|$K_I$ 
    & |(A13)[block]| $\medint\int dt$ 
    & |(A14)[junction]| 
    & |(A15)[input,  label={[font=\normalsize]above:$\hat{\omega}_e$}]| 
    & |(A16)[input,  label={[font=\normalsize]above:$x$}]|\\
%second row
      |(A21)[junction]| 
    & |(A22)[gain, inner sep=-.65mm]|$K_P$ 
    & 
    & |(A24)[sum]| 
    & |(A25)[block]| $\medint\int dt$ 
    & |(A26)[sum]| 
    & |(A27)[gain, inner sep=0pt]| $K_0$ \\
};

\graph[use existing nodes]{%
    A21->A22->A24->A25->A26->A27--[feedback]A21->[cornerupright]A12->A13->A15;
    A14->A24;
    A16->A26;};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I like it, this is very engineous! Though, why not use a `\foreach` do do the `\chainin`'s? Maybe for a bigger draw it would be very much useful.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos  Of course! You can use `{[start chain] \foreach \i in {1,2,4,5,6,7} \chainin (A-2-\i);}` or similar constructions.

Comment: This is very good, I love it! I was having some fun with it (I have nothing to do) and now I have little inputs to give: that last part (making the return wire) it's possible to make a third matrix row and eighth col using phantom nodes for `(A-2-8)`, `(A-3-1)` and `8` then, use the chain logic to connect them (I like it this way so everything is done in the same logic), you'd only need `phantom` style to be `coordinate` and the return chain should have the options `every join./style={-}` and `line cap=round`.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos With the second version, I'm sure you'll have more fun ;-).

Comment: you just killed _all_ the fun, now it's too simple... Of course I'm joking, that's really good, if the automatic naming could be used would be considerably awesom_er_. Although I still think it is better with an extra row and column for the Feedback part ;P (+2 if it was possible)

Comment: +1, the graph is interesting because it allows named (rather than numbered) references.

Comment: does graph require the use of `matrix`?

Comment: @JasonS No. You can use your previously `positioned` nodes and join them with `graph`.  You'll find more information in tutorial `Diagrams as simple graphs` (section 5 in pgfmanual).

Comment: Ah -- ok, I checked the tutorial and it looks fairly straightforward. Is there any way to also put `node [...]{sometext}` along the graph lines? (the way you can with `\draw[-] (foo) -- node [...]{sometext} (bar);`)