# `graph` command doesn't accept nodes named with `-`

Tags: tikz-pgf

It seems that a `\graph` command doesn't accept nodes whose name contains a `-`.

Compiling

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (A-1) {A};  
    \node[draw] (B-1) at (1,0) {B};
    \graph [use existing nodes] { A-1 -> B-1;};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

finishes with the error message:

`! Package tikz Error: One of the arrow types <-, --, ->, -!- or <-> expected.`

So it seems that the `-` (sorry I don't remember the name in English) is taken as an arrow and not as a part of node's name.

This is not a big problem because we can use names without `-`. But when nodes are declared with a `matrix of nodes`, they contain two `-`. This means that one of main advantages of a `matrix of nodes` which is automatic names can not be used and options `|(...)|` or `|[name=...]|` have to be used in every cell with a node.

Is there any way that `\graph` command accepts `-` in node's names?

Comment: $\sim$ might be a suitable substitute...

Comment: @kpie Huh? What are you talking about?

Comment: Wikipedia says $\sim$ is squirly dash in tex. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash

Comment: `\newcommand\Hyphen{-}` and `\graph [use existing nodes] { A\Hyphen 1 -> B\Hyphen 1;};` seems to work.

Comment: You can replace the definitions in `tikzlibrarygraphs.code.tex` line 649-715.

Comment: Or modify `tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex` line 24-41 so that matrix of nodes is named different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except that one can modify codes related to matrix or graph, here is an alternative.

The idea is that we usually *protect* sensitive characters by adding additional braces, for example `(\x,sin(\x))` does not work and `(\x,{sin(\x)})` does.

In case of graphs, braces have another meaning and we should *protect* node names by quotation marks. The ideal code should be like this

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (A-1) {A};
    \node[draw] (B-1) at (1,0) {B};
    \graph [use existing nodes] {"A-1"->"B-1";};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, anything putting inside quotation marks is processed for security reason: special characters are replaced by something else, for example `-` becomes `@HYPHEN MINUS@` and `>` becomes `@GREATER THAN SIGN@`. Therefore the following code actually works.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (A@HYPHEN MINUS@1) {A};
    \node[draw] (B@GREATER THAN SIGN@2) at (1,0) {B};
    \graph [use existing nodes] {"A-1"->"B>2";};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The Next step is that whenever we (or Ti*k*Z) create and name a node, we would like to replace `-` in the name by the same string above. Thus we hack the `name=` scheme

```
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    name/.code={
        {
            \catcode`\-=13\relax
            \scantokens{
                \def-{@HYPHEN MINUS@}
                \xdef\hypenminusname{#1}
            }
        }
        \edef\tikz@fig@name{\tikz@pp@name{\hypenminusname}}
    }
}
\makeatother
```

You can expand the list by yourself if there are other special characters involved.

Now The code at the beginning works. Also the following code works

```
\tikz{
    \matrix(magic)[matrix of nodes]{
        8 & 1 & 6 \\
        3 & 5 & 7 \\
        4 & 9 & 2 \\
    };
    \graph[use existing nodes]{
        "magic-2-1"->{"magic-1-3","magic-2-3","magic-3-3"};
    };
}
```

[image]

---

Full code

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,matrix}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (A@HYPHEN MINUS@1) {A};
    \node[draw] (B@GREATER THAN SIGN@2) at (1,0) {B};
    \graph [use existing nodes] {"A-1"->"B>2";};
\end{tikzpicture}

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    name/.code={
        {
            \catcode`\-=13\relax
            \scantokens{
                \def-{@HYPHEN MINUS@}
                \xdef\hypenminusname{#1}
            }
        }
        \edef\tikz@fig@name{\tikz@pp@name{\hypenminusname}}
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (A-1) {A};
    \node[draw] (B-1) at (1,0) {B};
    \graph [use existing nodes] {"A-1"->"B-1";};
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikz{
    \matrix(magic)[matrix of nodes]{
        8 & 1 & 6 \\
        3 & 5 & 7 \\
        4 & 9 & 2 \\
    };
    \graph[use existing nodes]{
        "magic-2-1"->{"magic-1-3","magic-2-3","magic-3-3"};
    };
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of hacking `graph` library or parsing, you can change the relevant parts of the `matrix of nodes` code. You can also make this a local behavior etc.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,matrix}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@empty@cell{\iftikz@lib@matrix@empty\node[name=\tikzmatrixname!\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow!\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]{};\fi}
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@with@options|#1|{\tikz@lib@matrix@plainfalse\node%
  [name=\tikzmatrixname!\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow!\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]#1\bgroup\tikz@lib@matrix@startup}
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@normal@start@cell{\pgfutil@ifnextchar\let{\tikz@lib@matrix@check}{\tikz@lib@matrix@plainfalse\node
  [name=\tikzmatrixname!\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow!\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]\bgroup\tikz@lib@matrix@startup}}%
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@check#1{% evil hackery to find out about start of path
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\tikz@signal@path{\tikz@lib@matrix@plaintrue\let}{\tikz@lib@matrix@plainfalse\node
  [name=\tikzmatrixname!\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow!\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn]\bgroup\tikz@lib@matrix@startup\let}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes] (a) {
A\\[4mm]
B\\
};
    \graph [use existing nodes] {a!1!1 -> a!2!1;};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```