# Left-Right Diagrams Latex TikZ

Tags: tikz-trees

I have create the following using Tikz.

```
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}


% Define block styles

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white, rounded corners,
                 minimum height=2em, minimum width =7em, text width=5em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
 % Place nodes

\node [block] (strategy) {\footnotesize Multimedia RSs};
\node [block, right of=strategy, node distance=3cm] (content) {\footnotesize Multimedia Content};

% Draw edges

\path [line] (strategy) -- (content);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the output looks like this:

[image]

I would like the box 'Multimedia Content' to appear on the **'North East'** and another box on the **'South East'** with arrows that are not oblique (*i.e.* combination of **horizontal** and **vertical** arrows). I am quite new to tikzz so your suggestions are very welcome.

P.s. as you can see the text size are huge although `\footnotesize`.

Comment: As always on this site, please post a full minimal example that others can copy and try without having to add anything. This greatly increases other peoples desire to help

Comment: Same as daleif, i don't know with packages and option are loaded, please include a working exemple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. There is the `chains` library of Ti*k*Z meant for this kind of drawings, though I think its meant for oblique connections. You can also use the `matrix` library like in: [Any easier way to draw lots of arrows in tikz?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/331613/114143), use `positioning` library and probrably many more.

Anyhow, below is a MWE using `matrix` because it's easier to have the `-|` and `|-` (combination of horizontal and vertical lines) and also a continuation of what you were doing.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\tikzset{block/.style={ rectangle,
                        draw,
                        fill=white,
                        rounded corners,
                        minimum height=2em,
                        minimum width =7em,
                        text width=5em},
         >=latex}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Using the matrix library
  % Make the grid
  \matrix (Media)[matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, column sep=2cm]
  {
                           &                                    &          & Subsubblock \\
                           &                                    & Subblock & \\
                           &                                    &          & Subsubblock \\
                           & |[block]| Multimedia content       &          & \\
                           &                                    &          & Subsubblock \\
                           &                                    & Subblock & \\
                           &                                    &          & Subsubblock \\
  |[block]| Multimedia RSs &                                    &          & \\
                           &                                    &          & Subsubblock \\
                           &                                    & Subblock & \\
                           &                                    &          & Subsubblock \\
                           & |[block]| Other Multimedia content &          & \\
                           &                                    &          & Subsubblock \\
                           &                                    & Subblock & \\
                           &                                    &          & Subsubblock \\
  };

  % Draw the lines
  \draw[->] (Media-2-1) -| +(2cm,0) |- (Media-1-2);
  \draw[->] (Media-2-1) -| +(2cm,0) |- (Media-3-2);

% Somewhat what you were doing - needs positioning and calc libraries
  \begin{scope}[xshift=6cm] %the scope here is just so graphics don't overlap in this example
  \node [block] (strategy) {\footnotesize Multimedia RSs};
  \node [block, above right=1cm of strategy] (content) {\footnotesize Multimedia Content};
  \node [block, below right=1cm of strategy] (content2) {\footnotesize Multimedia Content};

  \draw[->] (strategy) -| ($(strategy)!.5!(content)$) |- (content);
  \draw[->] (strategy) -| ($(strategy)!.5!(content2)$) |- (content2);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

By the way, to me seems like que `\footnotesize` is working normally.

[image]

Comment: Great. Your answer was very nice and complete. Can you please let me know if instead of two branches, we wish to have 3 or more branches how we can change the code e.g. using `matrix` ? Thanks

Comment: @Yas, I edited the answer to better show the `\matrix` command. If you see it, is much like `tabular` and the cells have automatic naming like this: `(MatrixName-row-column)` as you can see in the MWE, so to add more branches, just add more cells. For more Information on this please refer to the [Manual](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) as it is very complete and filled with examples.

Comment: In fact, the structure looks very clear to me. However, there is one last issue remaining and that is how can I subbranch from a subbranch. An example, suppose you want to subranch from Multimedia Content into two branches. Can we do this using `matrix` ?

Comment: Ah, sorry I think the answer is easy. We can just make a column matrix as you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But that would be the downside of the Matrix way. the bigger the fluxogram the bigger the tabular. Look on the edit, though the subblocks are not properly connected.

Comment: oh, Yes thanks. I think the lines in the code your shared need some change.

Comment: Indeed, missing `&`. Did it in a hurry... :/

Comment: Thanks A lot G.Z. Santos. Very useful discussion. I learned something new today !

Comment: Fixed the code. You are very much welcome, if you are up for learning new Ti*k*Z tricks, check the manual I linked, it can do things one would dare say impossible in LaTeX.

Comment: Yes, actually I looked at the manual. It's nice, well-written and through. Many thanks for its introduction !

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you actually draw a tree. Tree can relatively simple to draw by help of `tikz` library `trees` or by use of package  `forest`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,trees}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 2cm, 
every node/.style = {rectangle, draw, semithick, rounded corners,
                     inner sep=3mm, font=\footnotesize,
                     align=center},
  level distance = 33mm,
            grow = right,
edge from parent fork right,
edge from parent/.style = {draw, semithick, -stealth},
                        ]
\node {Multimedia\\ RSs}
    child { node {Multimedia\\ Content}}
    child { node {Multimedia\\ Content}}
    ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

  \begin{forest}
    for tree={
      font=\footnotesize,
      draw, semithick, rounded corners,
      align=center,
        inner sep = 3mm,
             edge = {draw, semithick, -stealth},
             grow = east,
    parent anchor = east,
     child anchor = west,
             grow = east,
      forked edge,
             l sep = 12mm% level distance
          fork sep = 6mm,
                }
    [Multimedia\\ RSs
      [Multimedia\\ Content]
      [Multimedia\\ Content]
    ]
  \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

result with `trees`:

[image]

result with `forest`

[image]

**Edit:**
By help of @cfr the solution using `forest` is improved with adding `fork sep = 6mm` to `for tree`. Now the branching point is on the middle of horizontal distance between nodes.

Comment: Don't put `forked edges` in the scope of `for tree` as it doubles the `for tree` which sometimes causes problems. Either use `forked edge` or take it out of `for tree`.

Comment: I still learning `forest` ... this is actually my first try to use it in an answer :-). Now I remember one of yours comments about this problem. However, after your correction code gives unacceptable
result, better is write `forked edges` outside scope for tree.  It seems, that I need to ask here a question about issues with `forked edge` (`forked edges`) directed to east or west. Than you for correction.

Comment: Sorry. I should have tested. I thought they were equivalent.

Comment: Problems were with parent/child anchors. I add them to code.

Comment: Oh, OK. They aren't equivalent. I don't know why I thought that. Using `forked edges` or specifying the anchor in a direction-agnostic way will make the code more flexible. This is how `forked edges` does it, in fact, if you look at the library's code. `forked edges/.style={
    for tree={parent anchor=children},
    for descendants={child anchor=parent,forked edge}
  },`