# Help with doing these arrows on this TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

I'm trying to draw the following picture with TikZ. The desired output is the following:

[image]

The problem is that I can't get a way to do two arrows like the ones I drew manually, departing from the green shapes. How can I do these kind of arrows? (The arrows should be on TikZ format, not like the ones I drew).

My code is the following so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,geometric,arrows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, text width=5cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!30]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=red!30]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>-stealth]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (start0) [process] {Inicio};
\node (start) [startstop, below of=start0] {Propiedades de la garganta a partir de cámara de combustión:\\
$P_0,T_0,\rho_0 \rightarrow P_t, T_t, \rho_t$};
\node (start1) [startstop, below of=start] {Presión de salida:\\
$P_s \rightarrow T_s, \rho_s, M_s, v_s, \varepsilon$};
\node (start2) [startstop, below of=start1] {Escoger dimensiones garganta y calcular mass flow:\\
$D_t \hspace{1mm} \mathrm{o} \hspace{1mm} A_t \rightarrow \dot{m}, A_s, F$};
\node (dec1) [decision, below of=start2, yshift=-0.75cm] {$ F\geq 500\hspace{1mm} \mathrm{N}?$};
\node (dec2) [decision, below of=dec1, yshift=-1.5cm] {$ P_s \leq P_s (\mathrm{min})$};
\node (end) [process, below of=dec2, yshift=-0.75cm] {Fin};


\draw [arrow] (start0) -- (start);
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (start1);
\draw [arrow] (start1) -- (start2);
\draw [arrow] (start2) -- (dec1);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) --  node[anchor=east] {Sí} (dec2);
\draw [arrow] (dec2) -- node[anchor=east] {Sí} (end);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is asked a few times a year, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102385