# Drawing a control diagram with graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am trying to create the attached diagram. But I can't seem to figure out how to create it. My code is shown below. Could someone please help me? Thanks for your help

[image]

```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node [draw=black!50, 
            minimum width=2cm,
            minimum height=1.2cm,
            fill=gray!5
            ]  (controller) {Extremum Seeking Controller};

            \node [draw=black!50, 
            minimum width=5cm,
            minimum height=3cm,
            above=1.5cm of controller, fill=gray!5
            ]  (plant) {Plant};

       % \draw[-stealth] (plant.east) -| (controller.east)

       \draw[] (plant.east) -- ++ (1.5,0) 
        node[](output){}node[midway,above]{};

        \draw[-stealth] (output.east) |- (controller.east);

        \draw[] (controller.west) --++  (-1.5,0) 
            node[](fromESCline){};

        \draw[-stealth] (fromESCline.west) |-  (plant.west) ;
            
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You need [some of these options](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102385) to connect nodes. For example `\draw[-stealth] (plant.east) -- ++ (1.5,0) node[align=center]{Plant \\Output} |- (controller); \draw[-stealth] (controller.west) --++  (-1.5,0) |- node[near end, align=center]{Manipulated\\Variables} (plant);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

[image]

whit this code (flat solution...):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[-latex] (2,1)--(-1,1)-=(-1,6)--(2,6);
        \draw (2,0) rectangle (8,1.7);
        \draw (2,2.5) rectangle (8,8);
        \draw (5,2.8) node () {\Large Plant};
        \draw[-latex] (8,6)--(11,6)--(11,1)--(8,1);
        \draw[-latex] (2.5,3.5)--(7.5,3.5) node[below] {\footnotesize $u_{ss}$};
        \draw[-latex] (2.5,3.5)--(2.5,7.5) node[right] {\footnotesize $y_{ss}$};
        %\clip (3,4) rectangle (7,7);
        \draw (3,4.5).. controls  (4.5,7) and (5,6.5)..(7,4);
        \draw[dashed] (2.5,6.2)--(4.5,6.2)--(4.5,3.5);
        \draw (2.5,6.2) node[left] () {\footnotesize $y$};
        \draw (4.5,3.5) node[below] () {\footnotesize $u$};
        \draw (5,1) node[] () {\large Extremum Seeking Controller};
        \draw (0.4,6) node[above] () {\large Manipulated};
        \draw (0.4,6) node[below] () {\large Variables};
        \draw (9.5,6) node[above] () {\large Plant};
        \draw (9.5,6) node[below] () {\large Output};   
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wanted to add that there is a possibility of having a node and simply including another graphics in it in case there is real data to be displayed . Good solution Raffaele.

Comment: @anis I need understanding better: You need only to change the central rectangle (Plant)?

Comment: All that I am saying is that I would have replaced the plant rectangle by `\node [rectangle] {\includegraphics[...]{...}`. But that is not a question. thank you.

Comment: Thank you @RaffaeleSantoro

Comment: @anis great suggestion. I did not know that it was possible to add a graph with real data. I will consider that option.

Comment: @tee you pay want to check the tikz library named datavisualization. You an even read CSV files directly and plot them.