# Latex TikZ arrow positionning in a flow chart

Tags: tikz-arrows, flow-charts

I want to make my flow chart looks better with positionning the arrow that goes from my decision node (Terminer?) to the third node (Evalution).

Thank you!

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
        \node (start) [startstop] {Démarrer};
        \node (pro1) [process, below of=start] {Population initiale};
        \node (pro2) [process, below of=pro1] {Evaluation};
        \node (pro3) [process, below of=pro2] {Fitness et sélection};
        \node (pro4) [process, below of=pro3] {Croisement};
        \node (pro5) [process, below of=pro4] {Mutation};
        \node (pro6) [process, below of=pro5] {Nouvelle génération};
        \node (dec1) [decision, below of=pro6] {Terminer?};
        \node (end) [startstop, below of=dec1] {Résultats};
        \draw [arrow] (start) -- (pro1);
        \draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
        \draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro3);
        \draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (pro4);
        \draw [arrow] (pro4) -- (pro5);
        \draw [arrow] (pro5) -- (pro6);
        \draw [arrow] (pro6) -- (dec1);
        \draw [arrow] (dec1) -- node [anchor=west] {Oui}(end);
        \draw [arrow] (dec1.west) |- node [anchor=west] {Non} (pro2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Algorithme génétique simple.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please make it a habit to post only code, which will compile ... yours won't. // Look for "|-" or "-|" in the pgfmanual. Even more so when you code doesn't tell, how [arrow] is defined ...

Comment: [Q102385](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102385) and many of the linked ones.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, always provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.