# Adding arrows in tikz block diagram

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-styles

How to add this line?

[image]
Current code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{fp, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,patterns,fadings,matrix,arrows,calc,
    intersections,decorations.markings,
    positioning,external,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle,
        minimum height=1cm,
        minimum width=2cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=6cm},
    arrow/.style={draw, -latex,node distance=2cm},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={latex-, black,node distance=2cm}},
    sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
}
\begin{document}


   \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, >=latex', transform shape,font={\sffamily \small}] 

    \node [draw=black,
    minimum width=1.6cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    align=center]   (1) {1};
    
    \node [draw=black,
    minimum width=1.6cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    align=center,
    right=0.6cm of 1]   (2) {2};
    
    \node [draw=black,
    minimum width=1.6cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    align=center,
    right=0.6cm of 2]   (3) {3}; 

    \draw[->,line width=0.25mm] (1.east) -- (2.west);
    \draw[->,line width=0.25mm] (2.east) -- (3.west);
    
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My try: `\draw[->,line width=0.25mm] ($(1)!0.5!(2)$) --++ (0,1cm) -|  (3);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `|-` to go first vertically and then horizontally from point A to point B. (Or `-|` for horizontal and then vertical movement.)

We can also use `2.east` as a rough marker. If we can `([yshift=1cm]2.east)` for the second point, we'll end up above the right most side of `2`. So we could say

```
$(1)!.5!(2)$ |- (yshift=1cm]2.east
```

for the first part. Now we need to go across a bit more, then down and then across to a point a bit above `3.west`. Let's take the halfway point between the `west` and `north west` anchors, `($(3.west)!.5!(3.north west)$)`.

We could manage the changes of direction with a manual adjustment and either `-|` or `|-`, but why go to the trouble if we don't have to?

The `ext.paths.ortho` library allows us to use an enhanced syntax for specifying paths. In our case `-|-` tells `tikz` to go horizontally, then vertically, then horizontally between two points.

```
\draw[->,line width=0.25mm] ($(1.east)!0.5!(2.west)$) |- ([yshift=1cm]2.east) -|- ($(3.west)!.5!(3.north west)$);
```

[image: diverted arrow up across across down across]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{fp, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,backgrounds,patterns,fadings,matrix,arrows,calc,
    intersections,decorations.markings,
    positioning,external,arrows.meta,ext.paths.ortho}
\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle,
        minimum height=1cm,
        minimum width=2cm},
    input/.style = {coordinate,node distance=1cm},
    output/.style = {coordinate,node distance=6cm},
    arrow/.style={draw, -latex,node distance=2cm},
    pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={latex-, black,node distance=2cm}},
    sum/.style = {draw, circle, node distance=1cm},
}
\begin{document}


   \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, >=latex', transform shape,font={\sffamily \small}] 

    \node [draw=black,
    minimum width=1.6cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    align=center]   (1) {1};
    
    \node [draw=black,
    minimum width=1.6cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    align=center,
    right=0.6cm of 1]   (2) {2};
    
    \node [draw=black,
    minimum width=1.6cm,
    minimum height=1.2cm, 
    align=center,
    right=0.6cm of 2]   (3) {3}; 

    \draw[->,line width=0.25mm] (1.east) -- (2.west);
    \draw[->,line width=0.25mm] (2.east) -- (3.west);
    \draw[->,line width=0.25mm] ($(1.east)!0.5!(2.west)$) |- ([yshift=1cm]2.east) -|- ($(3.west)!.5!(3.north west)$);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can name a coordinate on the segment from (1) to (2) just like a node. The midpoint of the line is the default. Then you can draw the new arrow from there.

The point `(3.160)` is on the boundary of node `(3)` at an angle of 160 degrees (slightly above `west` which would be 180). You could alternatively use `([yshift=3mm]3.west)` for the final point, which would be 3mm above center.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, arrows}

\tikzset{
    block/.style = {draw, rectangle, minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=1.6cm}
}

\begin{document}

   \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex',font={\sffamily\small}, node distance=.6cm] 

    \node [block] (1) {1};
    \node [block, right=of 1] (2) {2};
    \node [block, right=of 2] (3) {3}; 

    \draw[->,line width=0.25mm] (1) --coordinate(M1) (2);
    \draw[->,line width=0.25mm] (2) --coordinate(M2) (3);
    \draw[->,line width=0.25mm] (M1) |- ([yshift=9mm]M2) |- (3.160);

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/698846/) on your previous question, i.e. by use of the `chains` and `ext.paths.ortho` libraries. My MWE is focused only on your problem, so in comparison to your MWE it is quite shorter, however by the way it also show how can you block schemes can be drawn more efficiently:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                ext.paths.ortho,    % defined in the tikz-ext package
                positioning,
                }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 6mm,
  start chain = going right,
   arr/.style = {-{Straight Barb[scale=0.8]}, semithick},
   box/.style = {% default is rectangle
                 draw, minimum height = 10mm, minimum width=20mm,
                 on chain, join=by arr}
                        ]
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
    \node [box] (n\i) {\i};  % nodes are in chain
%
\path       (n1) -- coordinate  (aux) (n2);   % defined coordinate between nodes n1 and n2
\draw[arr]  (aux)  |- ([yshift=5mm] n2.north) % first part of arrow  
                  -|- [distance=-3mm] ([yshift=3mm] n3.west); % second part of arrow
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

[image]

Code (only `tikz` - no library):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=3pt] (0,0) node[minimum height=2cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (1) {\Huge \bfseries 1};
        \draw[line width=3pt] (5,0) node[minimum height=2cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (2) {\Huge \bfseries 2};
        \draw[line width=3pt] (10,0) node[minimum height=2cm,minimum width=3cm,draw] (3) {\Huge \bfseries 3};       
        \draw[-latex,line width=3pt] (1)  -- (2);
        \draw[-latex,line width=3pt] (2) -- (3);
        \draw[-latex,line width=3pt] (2.5,0)--(2.5,2)--(7.5,2)--(7.5,.5)--(8.5,.5);     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```