# Drawing chain with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote

I was answering a set of problems and found this picture. Since I am just starting to learn about TikZ, I have not been able to draw it.

[image]

Comment: Are there any rules on how the rings get smaller?

Comment: You need to create a ring shape (node) that so that you can fill it.  An arc version could handle the overlap.

Comment: Two circles.  Fill the outside black and the inside white.

Comment: I think you should not decide the accepted answer too early to avoid causing you to get confused and making you switch the accepted answer many times in a short period of time. Letting the time elapse about 12 hours or more seems to be good. :-)

Comment: OK, but I don't vote the last answer.

Comment: Up voting the answers that you think they are useful, good, etc is of course a good behavior.

Answer (score 17):

Clipping, and it needs my [`paths.ortho`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/16595) library.

#### Improvements/Problems

- Line widths are not accounted for.
- Keys instead of arguments.
- Keys also would allow to calculate a few things.
- Recursion.
- Adding missing upper and lower ring.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{paths.ortho}
\newcommand*\chainy[8]{% #1 = upper center       | #2 = lower center
                       % #3 = upper outer radius | #5 = lower outer radius
                       % #4 = upper inner radius | #6 = lower inner radius
                       % #7 = upper options      | #8 = lower options
\scope
  \clip (#1) -- ++(right:{#4}) arc[radius={#4}, start angle=0, delta angle=-90] --cycle
    ([shift=(right:{#3})] #1) coordinate (@)
    arc[radius={#3}, start angle=0, delta angle=-90] -- (#2) -- ++(right:{#5}) rl (@);
  \path[even odd rule, #8] (#2) circle [radius={#5}] (#2) circle [radius={#6}];
\endscope
\scope
  \clip (#2) -- ++(left:{#6}) arc[radius={#6}, start angle=180, delta angle=-90] --cycle
    ([shift=(left:{#5})] #2) coordinate (@)
    arc[radius={#5}, start angle=180, delta angle=-90] -- (#1) -- ++(left:{#3}) lr (@);
  \path[even odd rule, #7] (#1) circle [radius={#3}] (#1) circle [radius={#4}];
\endscope
\scope
  \clip (#1) rectangle ++ ({#3},{-#3});
  \path[even odd rule, #7] (#1) circle [radius={#3}] (#1) circle [radius={#4}];
\endscope
\scope
  \clip (#2) rectangle ++ ({-#5},{#5});
  \path[even odd rule, #8] (#2) circle [radius={#5}] (#2) circle [radius={#6}];
\endscope
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  udlr/rl distance=+0pt, udlr/lr distance=+0pt,
  y=5mm, x=5mm, a/.style={fill=blue}, b/.style={fill=red}]
  \chainy{0,0}  {0,-9} {6}{5}{5}{4}{a}{b}
  \chainy{0,-9} {0,-16}{5}{4}{4}{3}{b}{a}
  \chainy{0,-16}{0,-21}{4}{3}{3}{2}{a}{b}
  \chainy{0,-21}{0,-24}{3}{2}{2}{1}{b}{a}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: It is not work for me.

Comment: @kalakay I’m going to need more information to be able to help you. Error message? Unexpected output? UFOs instead of rings? You need to download the two files of the `paths.ortho` library I linked to.

Comment: I did, but here is https://www.writelatex.com/read/jhjsfzfnwmqt

Comment: Your algorithm is too complicated I think.

Comment: @kalakay: sorry, but you linked a document which exploit the PSTricks solution by Marienplatz. Moreover, as said by Qrrbrbirlbel, you need his library `paths.ortho`; I don't know how to include external libraries in writeLaTeX, but you definitely have to find a way.

Comment: I was upload the two files: tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code.tex and tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.tex as Qrrbrbirlbel said, but in writeLaTeX the files changed to tikzlibrarypaths_ortho_code.tex and tikzlibrarypaths_ortho.tex, and don't work.

Answer (score 16):

needs some time with `xelatex`. You can reduce the number of calculated polygons by modifying `ngrid`. `r1` is the outer radius of the ring and `r0` the radius of the ring itself:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,pstricks,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}    
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-3,-7)(3,10.2)
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=40 -10 0 rtp2xyz,Decran=100,ngrid=18 30,
       object=tore,r0=0.2,action=none}
\psSolid[r1=1,  RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=R1](0,0,3)
\psSolid[r1=0.9,RotX=90,RotZ=30,fillcolor=Brown, name=R2](0,0,1.5)
\psSolid[r1=0.8,RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=R3](0,0,0.1)
\psSolid[r1=0.7,RotX=90,RotZ=30,fillcolor=yellow,name=R4](0,0,-1)
\psSolid[r1=0.6, RotY=90,        fillcolor=green,name=R5](0,0,-2)
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=R1 R2 R3 R4 R5, action=draw**]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's awesome, because it's real 3D!

Comment: I guess it is `r0` and `r1` instead of `r1` and `r2`.

Answer (score 14):

A recommended solution with PSTricks. [The fewer key strokes the code use, the more readable the code is and the easier the code maintenance is.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwow5.jpg)

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt]{standalone}
\SpecialCoor
\psset{linewidth=.4,linecap=1}
\def\Atom#1#2#3#4#5{%
    \rput(0,#5){%
        \psarc[linecolor=#1](0,#3){!#3 .2 add}{180}{270}%
        \psarc[linecolor=#2](0,-#4){!#4 .2 add}{0}{180}%
        \psarc[linecolor=#1](0,#3){!#3 .2 add}{270}{360}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-12.5)(4,4)
    \Atom{red}{blue}{4}{3}{0}
    \Atom{blue}{red}{3}{2}{-6}
    \Atom{red}{blue}{2}{1}{-10}
    \Atom{blue}{red}{1}{.5}{-12}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My code above should be refactored to get a more friendly interface. I will do it later.

Comment: @kalakay: I am so sorry, I don't use TikZ.

Comment: Oh, it's OK, never mind.

Comment: I can see some sign where the two half arch meet... not very pleasant.

Comment: @Bakuriu: The unpleasant parts have been removed.

Answer (score 11):

[image]

A somewhat lazy approach without clipping, using a slightly overlapping sectors,
implemented in the `Asymptote` module `chainofrings.asy`. 
The structure `chainOfRings` uses two functions, `real Rscaled(int);`
and `real rscaled(int);` to define the major and minor radii of `i`-th ring.
`Figure 1c` demonstrates how to use a sequence of explicitly defined radii.

```
% chain.tex :
%
\begin{filecontents*}{chainofrings.asy}
struct chainOfRings{
  int n;             // number of rings
  real w;
  pair origin;
  pen[] clrA={deepgreen,deepblue};
  pen[] clrB={white,lightyellow,palered};
  guide qring;
  real Rscaled(int);
  real rscaled(int);
  real eps;

  void drawHalf(int i,real Rt,real rt, pair p,real phi){
    qring=rotate(phi)*(arc((0,0),Rt,-eps,90+eps)--reverse(arc((0,0),rt,-eps,90+eps))--cycle);
    radialshade(shift(p)*qring
    ,clrA[i%clrA.length], p, (Rt+rt)*0.382
    ,clrB[i%clrB.length], p, (Rt+rt)*0.618
    );
    radialshade(shift(p)*rotate(180)*qring
    ,clrA[i%clrA.length], p, (Rt+rt)*0.382
    ,clrB[i%clrB.length], p, (Rt+rt)*0.618
    );
  }

  void drawChain(){
    pair p;
    real Rt,rt,dh;
    p=origin; Rt=Rscaled(0); rt=rscaled(0); 
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      dh=rt;
      drawHalf(i,Rt, rt, p,0);
      Rt=Rscaled(i+1); rt=rscaled(i+1);
      w=Rt-rt;
      assert(Rt>rt && rt>0 && w>0);
      p+=(0,-(dh+Rt-w));
    }
    p=origin; Rt=Rscaled(0); rt=rscaled(0); 
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      dh=rt;
      drawHalf(i,Rt, rt, p,90);
      Rt=Rscaled(i+1); rt=rscaled(i+1);
      w=Rt-rt;
      assert(Rt>rt && rt>0 && w>0);
      p+=(0,-(dh+Rt-w));
    }
  }

  void operator init(pair origin=(0,0),int n=3,real Rscaled(int),real rscaled(int)
    ,pen[] clrA={gray(0.5),gray(0.7)}
    ,pen[] clrB={white,black}
    ,real eps=0.1
  ){
    this.origin=origin; this.n=n;  
    this.Rscaled=Rscaled;
    this.rscaled=rscaled;
    this.clrA=copy(clrA);
    this.clrB=copy(clrB);
    this.eps=eps;
  }
}
\end{filecontents*}
%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{justification=centering}
    \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
size(8cm);
import chainofrings;
real Rscaled(int k){return 10-4/3*k;};
real rscaled(int k){return 7-k;};

chainOfRings(origin=(0,0),n=4,Rscaled,rscaled).drawChain();    
\end{asy}
%
\caption{Using default colors}
\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
size(8cm);
import chainofrings;
real Rscaled(int k){return 10-4/3*k;};
real rscaled(int k){return 7-k;};

chainOfRings cr=chainOfRings(origin=(30,0),n=6,Rscaled,rscaled
  ,clrA=new pen[]{deepred,deepblue}
  ,clrB=new pen[]{white,lightyellow,palered}
);
cr.drawChain();
\end{asy}
%
\caption{Using custom colors}
\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
size(8cm);
import chainofrings;
real Rscaled(int k){
  real[] R={20,10,5,10};
  return R[k%R.length];
};
real rscaled(int k){
  real[] r={18,6,4.5,7};
  return r[k%r.length];
};

chainOfRings cr=chainOfRings(origin=(30,0),n=8,Rscaled,rscaled
  ,clrA=new pen[]{deepred,deepblue}
  ,clrB=new pen[]{white,lightyellow,palered}
);
cr.drawChain();
\end{asy}
%
\caption{Using a set of radii}
\label{fig:1c}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Chains of rings} \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
%
% Process:
%
% pdflatex chain.tex
% asy chain-*.asy
% pdflatex chain.tex
```

Answer (score 11):

The original drawing seems out of proportion, but anyway, this requires the latest CVS version of `PGF` for the `math` library.

Two versions are shown below. In the first version, the right half of each ring is drawn first 'top to bottom' and the the left halves are drawn 'bottom to top'.

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.5pt, y=2.5pt, line cap=round, thick, font=\sf, >=stealth]
\tikzmath{
    %
    % Thickness
    \t = 1; 
    % Outer Diameters
    let \D = {{20, 16, 12, 8}};
    %
    \y = 0;
    \s = 0.5;
    %
    int \i;
    for \i in {0,...,3}{
        \r =  \D[\i]/2;
        if (\i > 0) then {
            \y = \y - \r - \D[\i-1]/2 + 2*\t + \s;
        };
        \p = int(mod(\i,2)*100);
        {
            \fill [orange!\p!red] (0,\y) ++(90:\r) arc (90:-90:\r)  -- ++(0,\t) arc (-90:90:\r-\t) -- cycle; 
        };
    };
    for \i in {3,...,0}{
        \r =  \D[\i]/2;
        if (\i < 3) then {
            \y = \y + \r + \D[\i+1]/2 - 2*\t - \s;
        };
        \p = int(mod(\i,2)*100);
        {
            % Overlap the arcs so no white lines in PDF viewers
            \fill [orange!\p!red] (0,\y) ++(85:\r) arc (85:275:\r)  -- ++(0,\t) arc (275:85:\r-\t) -- cycle; 
        };
    };
    int \M;
    \M1 = \D[0];
    \M2 = \D[0] - 2*\t;     
}

\draw [thick] (0, \M1/2)  -- ++(+20,0) ++(-5, 0) coordinate (a1);
\draw [thick] (0, -\M1/2) -- ++(+20,0) ++(-5, 0) coordinate (a2);

\draw [thick] (0, \M2/2)  -- ++(-20,0) ++(5, 0) coordinate (b1);
\draw [thick] (0, -\M2/2) -- ++(-20,0) ++(5, 0) coordinate (b2);

\draw [<->] (a1) -- (a2) node [midway, right] {\M1};
\draw [<->] (b1) -- (b2) node [midway, left] {\M2};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But the 'two pass' system used above is a bit inefficient. Here is a version using layers, so the rings can be drawn 'in one go':

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=2.5pt, y=2.5pt, line cap=round, thick, font=\sf, >=stealth]
\tikzmath{
    %
    % Thickness
    \t = 1; 
    % Outer Diameters
    let \D = {{20, 16, 12, 8}};
    %
    \y = 0;
    \s = 0.5;
    %
    int \i;
    for \i in {0,...,3}{
        \r =  \D[\i]/2;
        if (\i > 0) then {
            \y = \y - \r - \D[\i-1]/2 + 2*\t + \s;
        };
        \p = int(mod(\i,2)*100);
        {
            \fill [orange!\p!red] (0,\y) ++(90:\r) arc (90:360:\r)  -- ++(-\t, 0) arc (360:90:\r-\t) -- cycle; 
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
                \fill [orange!\p!red] (0,\y) ++(95:\r) arc (95:-5:\r)  -- ++(-5:-\t) arc (-5:95:\r-\t) -- cycle;
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        };
    };
    int \M;
    \M1 = \D[0];
    \M2 = \D[0] - 2*\t;     
}

\draw [thick] (0, \M1/2)  -- ++(+20,0) ++(-5, 0) coordinate (a1);
\draw [thick] (0, -\M1/2) -- ++(+20,0) ++(-5, 0) coordinate (a2);

\draw [thick] (0, \M2/2)  -- ++(-20,0) ++(5, 0) coordinate (b1);
\draw [thick] (0, -\M2/2) -- ++(-20,0) ++(5, 0) coordinate (b2);

\draw [<->] (a1) -- (a2) node [midway, right] {\M1};
\draw [<->] (b1) -- (b2) node [midway, left] {\M2};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.

Or...

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main}

\newbox\ringbox
\def\ring#1#2#3#4{%
    \def\ringColor{#1}%
    \def\radius{#2}%
    \def\ringThickness{#3}%
    \def\highlightColor{\ringColor!25!white}
    \def\lowlightColor{\ringColor!35!black}
    \setbox\ringbox=\hbox{%
        \tikzmath{%
            \xf = #4;
            {
                \fill [even odd rule, \ringColor] 
                    circle [x radius=\xf*\radius, y radius=\radius] 
                    circle [x radius=\xf*\radius-\ringThickness, y radius=\radius-\ringThickness];
            };
            for \l in {0,0.5,...,5}{
                \t = \l*\ringThickness*3;
                \o = 0.05;
                \angleA = 45+\l*5;
                \angleB = 225-\l*5;
                \ry1 = \radius-\ringThickness/10*3;
                \ry2 = \radius-\ringThickness/10*7;
                \rx1 = \ry1 * \xf;
                \rx2 = \ry2 * \xf;
                {
                    \draw [\highlightColor, opacity=\o,line width=\t, line cap=round]
                        (\angleA:\rx1 and \ry1) arc (\angleA:\angleB:\rx1 and \ry1)
                        [rotate=180]
                        (\angleA:\rx2 and \ry2) arc (\angleA:\angleB:\rx2 and \ry2); 
                    \draw [\lowlightColor, opacity=\o,line width=\t, line cap=round]
                    (\angleA:\rx2 and \ry2) arc (\angleA:\angleB:\rx2 and \ry2)
                    [rotate=180]
                        (\angleA:\rx1 and \ry1) arc (\angleA:\angleB:\rx1 and \ry1);
                };
            };
        }%
    }%
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0,0) -- (90:\radius) arc (90:365:\radius) -- cycle;
        \copy\ringbox
    \end{scope}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) -- (91:\radius) arc (91:0:\radius) -- cycle;
            \copy\ringbox
        \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\ring{red}{10}{2}{1}
\tikzset{shift=(270:10+8-4)}
\ring{orange}{8}{2}{0.875}
\tikzset{shift=(270:8+6-4)}
\ring{red}{6}{2}{1}
\tikzset{shift=(270:6+4-4)}
\ring{orange}{4}{2}{0.875}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: They are magnetized chains as there is air gap between two adjacent chains.

Comment: @Marienplatz so where the code says `\s = 0.5;` use `\s = 0;`.

Answer (score 10):

My answer is based on the solution of Qrrbrbirlbel but with a simpler TikZ approach.

There is two macros (`\chainyr` and `\chainyl`) to change the orientation of superpositions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\chainyr[8]{% #1 = upper center       | #2 = lower center
                        % #3 = upper outer radius | #5 = lower outer radius
                        % #4 = upper inner radius | #6 = lower inner radius
                        % #7 = upper options      | #8 = lower options

  \begin{scope}[shift={(#2)}]
    \path[#8] (0:#6) -- (0:#5) arc (0:90:#5) -- (90:#6) arc (90:0:#6) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
    \path[#7] (0:#4) -- (0:#3) arc (0:-180:#3) -- (-180:#4) arc (-180:0:#4) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(#2)}]
    \path[#8] (90:#6) -- (90:#5) arc (90:180:#5) -- (180:#6) arc (180:90:#6) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
}
\newcommand*\chainyl[8]{% #1 = upper center       | #2 = lower center
                        % #3 = upper outer radius | #5 = lower outer radius
                        % #4 = upper inner radius | #6 = lower inner radius
                        % #7 = upper options      | #8 = lower options

  \begin{scope}[shift={(#2)}]
    \path[#8] (90:#6) -- (90:#5) arc (90:180:#5) -- (180:#6) arc (180:90:#6) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(#1)}]
    \path[#7] (0:#4) -- (0:#3) arc (0:-180:#3) -- (-180:#4) arc (-180:0:#4) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(#2)}]
    \path[#8] (0:#6) -- (0:#5) arc (0:90:#5) -- (90:#6) arc (90:0:#6) -- cycle;
  \end{scope}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [line width=.1pt,
  a/.style={fill=orange,draw=orange},
  b/.style={fill=violet,draw=violet}]
  \chainyr{0,0}  {0,-9} {6}{5}{5}{4}{a}{b}
  \chainyl{0,-9} {0,-16}{5}{4}{4}{3}{b}{a}
  \chainyr{0,-16}{0,-21}{4}{3}{3}{2}{a}{b}
  \chainyl{0,-21}{0,-24}{3}{2}{2}{1}{b}{a}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, Paul! This one seems to be more easily understood to me.

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative without `paths.ortho`.

[image]

Code:

Define a ring (called chain) via clip with radii and color parameters available.  `#1=outter circle`, `#2=color`, `#3=inner circle`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1cm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{matrix, shapes, arrows, positioning}

\newcommand\chain[3]{%  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\clip (0,0) circle (#1 mm);
\fill[#2] (0,0) circle (#1 mm);
\clip (0,0) circle (#3 mm);
\fill[white] (0,0) circle (#3 mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
```

Put rings into a chain by node with coordinates (user defined), then fill the overlay again to show which is 'front' and which is 'behind'.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0)          {\chain{10}{black}{9}};

\node at (0,-15mm) {\chain{8}{red}{7}};
\fill [black] (-60:9 mm) -- (-60:10 mm) arc (-60:-113:10 mm) -- (-109:9 mm) arc (-109: -60:9 mm);

\node at (0,-26mm) {\chain{6}{blue}{5}};
\fill [red,yshift=-15mm] (-50:7 mm) -- (-50:8 mm) arc (-50:-115:8mm) -- (-111:7 mm) arc (-111:-50:7 mm);

\node at (0,-33mm) {\chain{4}{yellow}{3}};
\fill [blue,yshift=-26mm] (-50:5 mm) -- (-50:6 mm) arc (-50:-115:6mm) -- (-111:5 mm) arc (-111: -50:5 mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's work and answed, just put the measures.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a code golfing exercise ... here is a <s>264</s> 244 characters tikz solution ;)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\def~#1.{pic[#1]{p}[cm={-.84,0,0,.84,(a)}](a)}
\begin{document}
\tikz\path[transform shape,p/.pic={\fill(0,0)arc(90:-90:1)node(a){}++(0,-.4)arc(-90:90:1.4);}]
{~.~red.~.~red.}[xscale=-1]~.~red.~.~red.;
\end{document}
```

[image]