# Removal of grid lines in pst-solides3d object

Tags: pst-solides3d

Is it possible to either remove the grid lines in a `pst-solides3d` object or make them thinner? Specifically, I'm thinking of the rings in Herbert's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140838/15874).

I have had a look in the [manual](http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d-doc.pdf) but I can't seem to find anything regarding the issue mentioned.

**Update**

This is a follow-up question: I think it should be

```
\psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=20 100,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=R1](0,0,3)
\psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=20 90, RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=green, name=R2](0,0,1.5)
\psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=20 80,         RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=R3](0,0,0.2)
\psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=20 70, RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=yellow,name=R4](0,0,-0.9)
\psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=20 60,         RotY=90,        fillcolor=Purple,name=R5](0,0,-1.8)
```

in Herbert's answer in the other question.

Then we have the following:

(1) The grid 'tiles' are square-looking.

(2) With the new coordinates for the rings, they are not 'floating' or overlapping when interlocked with one another.

Am I right on this?

**Update 2**

The rings can be smoothened even further but the code takes a *very* long time to compile (using XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[
  dvipsnames
]{article}

\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-2.9,-7.95)(2.9,10.45)
   \psset{
     lightsrc=viewpoint,
     viewpoint=40 -10 0 rtp2xyz,
     Decran=100,
     object=tore,
     r0=0.2,
     action=none
   }
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=66 330,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=R1](0,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=66 297,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=green, name=R2](0,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=66 264,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=R3](0,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=66 231,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=gray,  name=R4](0,0,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=66 198,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=yellow,name=R5](0,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=66 165,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=Purple,name=R6](0,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[
      object=fusion,
      base=R1 R2 R3 R4 R5 R6,
      linewidth=0.1pt,
      linecolor=black!60,
      action=draw**
    ]
  \end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

P.S. I have added an extra ring and changed the colours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the width uses the `linewidth=<dimen>` key-value. To remove it, set `linewidth=0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}% http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-3,-7)(3,10.2)
\psset{lightsrc=viewpoint,viewpoint=40 -10 0 rtp2xyz,Decran=100,ngrid=18 30,
       object=tore,r0=0.2,action=none,linewidth=0pt}
\psSolid[r1=1,  RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=R1](0,0,3)
\psSolid[r1=0.9,RotX=90,RotZ=30,fillcolor=Brown, name=R2](0,0,1.5)
\psSolid[r1=0.8,RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=R3](0,0,0.1)
\psSolid[r1=0.7,RotX=90,RotZ=30,fillcolor=yellow,name=R4](0,0,-1)
\psSolid[r1=0.6, RotY=90,        fillcolor=green,name=R5](0,0,-2)
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=R1 R2 R3 R4 R5, action=draw**]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

A minor artifact of the visual display should not be visible in the printed media. Zooming in at high detail should confirm this:

[image]

You could also set it to a smaller, non-zero dimension, but change the colour to match that of the object. However, since [`pst-solides3d`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) applied shading to surfaces based on a light source, this will not always display the desired effect.

You can change the line color (if needed) using the regular `linecolor=<colour>` key-value.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: [Herbert's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141028/5764) confirms that this is the case, not being able to set `linecolor` individually. If you had a single object with some light/shading, colour setting the rules and fill to be similar might lessen the visual artifacts.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: Your update shows a nicer (smoother) layout of the rings, however, the compile time (on the rendering side) is much longer. But this is to be expected.

Answer (score 4):

`linewidth` and `linecolor` can *not* be set individually for the rings. It is only possible for the last fusion object which collects all polygons with its direction vector to decide which is visible and which not.

```
\psSolid[object=fusion,base=R1 R2 R3 R4 R5, action=draw**,linewidth=0.2pt,linecolor=black!50]
```

[image]

For any viewer and any magnification you get some Moiré pattern:

[image]

Comment: Please see my updated answer, Herbert. (This also applies to [your other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/140838/15874).)