# PSTricks code not compiling

Tags: pst-solides3d

The following code is an attempt to extend Herbert's figure [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140699/drawing-chain-with-tikz/140838#140838):

```
\documentclass[
  dvipsnames
]{article}

\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.4cm,
  vmargin=3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-5.9,-7.95)(5.9,10.45)
   \psset{
     lightsrc=viewpoint,
     viewpoint=40 -10 0 rtp2xyz,
     Decran=100,
     grid=false,
     object=tore,
     r0=0.2,
     action=none
   }
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=S1](-3,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=green, name=S2](-3,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=S3](-3,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=gray,  name=S4](-3,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=yellow,name=S5](-3,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=10 25,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=Purple,name=S6](-3,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[
      object=fusion,
      base=S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6,
      linewidth=0.1pt,
      linecolor=black!60,
      action=draw**
    ]
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=T1](3,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=green, name=T2](3,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=T3](3,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=gray,  name=T4](3,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=yellow,name=T5](3,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=10 25,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=Purple,name=T6](3,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[
      object=fusion,
      base=T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6,
      grid=false,
      linewidth=0.1pt,
      linecolor=black!60,
      action=draw**
    ]
  \end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

(It takes about 25 seconds to compile the code, using XeLaTeX, on my computer.)

Her is the error:

```
[1] (./test.aux)Error: /typecheck in --add--
Operand stack:
   les_sommets   --nostringval--   0.0   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   1867   1   3   %oparray_pop   1755   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   359   --nostringval--   %repeat_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1175/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:117/200(L)--   --dict:754/1012(L)--   --dict:206/300(L)--   --dict:754/1012(L)--   --dict:2/3(L)--   --dict:3/3(L)--   --dict:6/6(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Not a directory
Current file position is 10322
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

** WARNING ** Filtering file via command -->rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dEPSCrop -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.5 -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilterColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile='/tmp/dvipdfmx.XXFBpfjq' '/tmp/dvipdfmx.XXat2UdM' -c quit<-- failed.
** WARNING ** Image format conversion for PSTricks failed.
** WARNING ** Interpreting special command pst: (ps:) failed.
** WARNING ** >> at page="1" position="(306, 410.74)" (in PDF)
** WARNING ** >> xxx "pst:  tx@Dict begin STP newpath   1. .setopacityalpha  1 setlin"
 )
```

What do I have to change to make the code compilable?
How do I fix this?

**Update**

After help from Werner, the following is what I ended up with:

```
\documentclass[
  dvipsnames
]{article}

\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.4cm,
  vmargin=3cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4.8,-7.75)(4.8,10.2)
   \psset{
     lightsrc=viewpoint,
     Decran=100,
     object=tore,
     r0=0.2,
     action=none
   }
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=blue,  name=S1](-1.5,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=green, name=S2](-1.5,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=red,   name=S3](-1.5,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=gray,  name=S4](-1.5,0,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=yellow,name=S5](-1.5,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=10 25,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=Purple,name=S6](-1.5,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[
      viewpoint=40 45 0 rtp2xyz,
      object=fusion,
      base=S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6,
      grid=false,
      action=draw**
    ]
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=blue,  name=T1](1.5,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=green, name=T2](1.5,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=red,   name=T3](1.5,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=gray,  name=T4](1.5,0,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=yellow,name=T5](1.5,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=10 25,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=Purple,name=T6](1.5,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[
      viewpoint=40 135 0 rtp2xyz,
      object=fusion,
      base=T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6,
      linewidth=0.1pt,
      linecolor=black!60,
      action=draw**
    ]
  \end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: it makes no sense to set the viewpoint for the fusion object. It should be set _before_ all objects which depend on that setting.

Comment: @Herbert Any chance I can make you give an answer with the correct way of doing this?

Comment: see my answer ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solids `S4` and `T4` are both set at locations consisting of only 2 dimensions `(-3,-0.9)`/`(3,-0.9)` while you need 3 dimensions. I've done so using `(-3,0,-0.9)`/`(3,0,-0.9)` in the MWE below:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  dvipsnames
]{article}

\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.4cm,
  vmargin=3cm
]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}% tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-5.9,-7.95)(5.9,10.45)
   \psset{
     lightsrc=viewpoint,
     viewpoint=40 -10 0 rtp2xyz,
     Decran=100,
     grid=false,
     object=tore,
     r0=0.2,
     action=none
   }
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=S1](-3,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=green, name=S2](-3,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=S3](-3,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=gray,  name=S4](-3,0,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=yellow,name=S5](-3,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=10 25,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=Purple,name=S6](-3,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[
      object=fusion,
      base=S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6,
      linewidth=0.1pt,
      linecolor=black!60,
      action=draw**
    ]
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=T1](3,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=green, name=T2](3,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=T3](3,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=gray,  name=T4](3,0,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=yellow,name=T5](3,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=10 25,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=Purple,name=T6](3,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[
      object=fusion,
      base=T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6,
      grid=false,
      linewidth=0.1pt,
      linecolor=black!60,
      action=draw**
    ]
  \end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

You could also change the viewpoint to see the chains from the same distance. Below I've used `viewpoint=0 -40 0`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
  dvipsnames
]{article}

\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.4cm,
  vmargin=3cm
]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}% tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-5.9,-7.95)(5.9,10.45)
   \psset{
     lightsrc=viewpoint,
     viewpoint=0 -40 0,
     Decran=100,
     grid=false,
     object=tore,
     r0=0.2,
     action=none
   }
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=S1](-3,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=green, name=S2](-3,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=S3](-3,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=gray,  name=S4](-3,0,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=yellow,name=S5](-3,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=10 25,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=Purple,name=S6](-3,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[
      object=fusion,
      base=S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6,
      linewidth=0.1pt,
      linecolor=black!60,
      action=draw**
    ]
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=blue,  name=T1](3,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=green, name=T2](3,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=red,   name=T3](3,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=gray,  name=T4](3,0,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,        fillcolor=yellow,name=T5](3,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=10 25,RotX=90,        RotZ=30,fillcolor=Purple,name=T6](3,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[
      object=fusion,
      base=T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6,
      grid=false,
      linewidth=0.1pt,
      linecolor=black!60,
      action=draw**
    ]
  \end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Note that since you're placing the objects in 3D using Cartesian coordinates, I've stuck with Cartesian coordinates for placement of the viewpoint (dropping the conversion `rtp2xyz`).

---

In light of some difficulty understanding the `viewpoint` (and possibly the light source `lightsrc`), here is an animated graphic with a *fixed* light source at (x,y,z)=(0,-40,0) and *moving* the viewpoint (in spherical coordinates) around the object in 10 degree increments, starting from `40 90 0 rtp2xyz`:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Werner! I now have a follow-up question (see updated question).

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: That's because you are viewing the solids in 3D based on a specific `viewpoint`. Specifically your viewpoint is set to be "far over in the x-direction" (since x = 40), implying that you're closer to the `T`-object. And closer objects appear larger, while further objects appear smaller. For an equal view on the objects, you should probably use `viewpoint=0 -10 0 rtp2xyz`.

Comment: Then (1) the chains are top of each other, (2) one of them are up-side down, and (3) one is still bigger than the other; I'll try to fiddle with it and return.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg: I just noticed you're actually transforming your coordinates from spherical `rtp` to Cartesian `xyz`. How about just using Cartesian: `viewpoint=0 -40 0` (just a guess). Experimentation would yield the best solution...

Comment: That produces an error.

Comment: @werner

Can you describe how you managed the variable of the viewpoint?

Answer (score 3):

Your rings are placed along the x-axis. If you want both in the same size then you have to view it along the y-axis!

```
viewpoint=40 90 20 rtp2xyz
```

which is: `radius=40`, `theta=90` (rotation around z), `phi=20`

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-4.8,-7.75)(4.8,10.2)
   \psset{viewpoint=40 90 20 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,
     Decran=100,object=tore,r0=0.2,action=none}
    \axesIIID(4,4,4)
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=blue,  name=S1](-1.5,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=green, name=S2](-1.5,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=red,   name=S3](-1.5,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=gray,  name=S4](-1.5,0,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=yellow,name=S5](-1.5,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=10 25,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=Purple,name=S6](-1.5,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[object=fusion,base=S1 S2 S3 S4 S5 S6,grid,action=draw**]
    \psSolid[r1=1,  ngrid=10 50,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=blue,  name=T1](1.5,0,3)
    \psSolid[r1=0.9,ngrid=10 45,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=green, name=T2](1.5,0,1.5)
    \psSolid[r1=0.8,ngrid=10 40,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=red,   name=T3](1.5,0,0.2)
    \psSolid[r1=0.7,ngrid=10 35,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=gray,  name=T4](1.5,0,-0.9)
    \psSolid[r1=0.6,ngrid=10 30,        RotY=90,       fillcolor=yellow,name=T5](1.5,0,-1.8)
    \psSolid[r1=0.5,ngrid=10 25,RotX=90,        RotZ=0,fillcolor=Purple,name=T6](1.5,0,-2.5)
    \psSolid[object=fusion,base=T1 T2 T3 T4 T5 T6,grid,action=draw**]
  \end{pspicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]