# How to create a bent arrow at a rectangle corner?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I have created a rectangle and just can't find the solution how to draw a bent arrow from the south side (close to the south east corner) to the east side (also close to the south east corner).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report}     
\usepackage{a4} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,arrows,backgrounds,calendar,matrix,mindmap,patterns,shadows,trees,positioning}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,
    block_small/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white, text centered, text width=4em, minimum height=4em}]  

\node [block_small, xshift=-3.3cm] (A) {A} ;
\node [block_small,right of=A, xshift=3.3cm] (B) {B} ; 

\begin{pgfonlayer}{background} 

   % Rectangle             
    \path (A.west |- A.north)+(-0.45,0.45) node (a) {};
    \path (B.south -| B.east)+(0.45,-0.45) node (b) {};
    \path[draw=black!50, dashed] (a) rectangle (b);

\end{pgfonlayer} 

\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

I have spent already too much time on this and hope someone may help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: That looks like a job for Qrrbrbirlbel's [`paths.ortho` library](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/2552).

Comment: The arc is expecting arc `(start angle:end angle:radius)`, so for the other corner it would be `arc (-180:90:0.5)`. If you would do `arc (180:90:0.5)` it would just draw a qurter circle clockwise. If you don't like negative angles, you can also specify angles larger than 360 degree, so `arc (180:450:0.5)` would also work.

Answer (score 9):

- You can construct the box easier with the **fit** library. Just put `fit=(a1)(a2)...(an)` into the options of a new node, with `inner sep=<length>` you can control the distance to all the fitted nodes.
- The **calc** library lets you do things like `($(a)+(0,1)$)` which is the position 1 unit up from node a. With that you can do things like *"from the south side (close to the south east corner)"*
- for a bent arrow, you can use the `to[out=<deg>,in=<deg>,looseness=<val>]` operation. If you dont like this arrow, you can also specify more intermediate points. If the arrow starts and ends at the same distance from the corner, you can also use an `arc`. Arcs are specified via `arc (start angle:end angle:radius)`

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{report} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,arrows}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
[   auto, node distance=1cm,
  block_small/.style ={rectangle, draw=black, thick, fill=white, text centered, text width=4em, minimum height=4em}
]
    \node [block_small, xshift=-3.3cm] (A) {A} ;
    \node [block_small,right of=A, xshift=3.3cm] (B) {B} ; 

    % Rectangle             
    \node[fit=(A)(B),dashed,draw,inner sep=0.45cm] (Box) {};

    \draw[-stealth] ($(Box.south east)+(-0.5,0)$) to[out=270,in=0,looseness=5] node[below right] {$\pi$} ($(Box.south east)+(0,0.5)$);

    \draw[-stealth] ($(Box.south west)+(0.5,0)$) arc (360:90:0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The left one is exactly what I wanted. I now tried to switch it to the south east side playing around with the parameters such as \draw[-stealth] ($(Box.south east)+(-0.5,0)$) arc (360:90:0.5); However, it does not bend in the right dirextion. I hope you can help again. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `[xshift=]` and friends makes it easier to arrange shifts etc. without the `calc` dependence