# More efficient way to draw movement arrow to roof in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, linguistics, tikz-qtree

When drawing syntactic representations in linguistics, one often uses a triangle to represent a unit whose internal structure is irrelevant. This can be accomplished with the `tikz-qtree` command `\edge[roof]; {John}`.

Now, sometimes I need to show the movement of such a unit whose internal structure is irrelevant to the point at hand. To do this, I usually make use of the `positioning` library, and define a node relative to the node above the triangle, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.TP
    [.\node(DP1-rel){DP}; \edge[roof]; {John} ]
    [.T$'$
        [.T ]
        [.\emph{v}P
            [.\node(DP2-rel){DP}; \edge[roof]; {$<$John$>$} ]
            [.\emph{v}$'$
                [.\emph{v}
                    [.V \node(V1){likes}; ]
                    [.\emph{v} ]
                ]
                [.VP
                    [.V \node(V2){$<$likes$>$}; ]
                    [.DP \edge[roof]; {Mary} ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\node (DP1) [below=1cm of DP1-rel] {};
\node (DP2) [below=1cm of DP2-rel] {};
\draw[->] (DP2)..controls +(south west:1) and +(south:1)..(DP1);
\draw[->] (V2)..controls +(south:1) and +(south:1)..(V1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: syntactic-tree]

Is there an easier/better way to do this, where I don't have to define a relative node each time I need to move a unit whose internal structure is irrelevant (*i.e.*, whose structure I'm representing with a triangle, using the `tikz-qtree` command `\edge[roof]; {John}`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just make the text of the roof a node. (I also simplified the arrow syntax a bit.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center, anchor=north}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.TP
    [.DP \edge[roof]; \node (J) {John}; ]
    [.T$'$
        [.T ]
        [.\emph{v}P
            [.DP \edge[roof]; \node (Jtrace) {$<$John$>$}; ]
            [.\emph{v}$'$
                [.\emph{v}
                    [.V \node(V1){likes}; ]
                    [.\emph{v} ]
                ]
                [.VP
                    [.V \node(V2){$<$likes$>$}; ]
                    [.DP \edge[roof]; {Mary} ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]

\draw[->] (Jtrace) [in=-90,out=-90,looseness=1.5]  to (J);
\draw[->] (V2) [in=-90,out=-90]  to (V1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Huh, nice, I didn't know you could do that. I always tried putting the `node` inside of the `{}`. Thanks, Alan! Thanks for the simpler way of drawing arrows, too.

Answer (score 3):

I don’t know about `tikz-qtree` but with [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest), you can access the tree’s node with the special `!` syntax. The node `(!2211)` (in your examples, this is `<John>`), is the root’s (`TP`) second child’s (`T'`) second child’s (`vP`) first child’s (`DP`) first child (`<John>`).

Then, there is always the possibility to give a node a name with the usual TikZ key: `name` (or `alias` if you need more than one name).

There is also the possibility to give a node that is relative to another (which is actually the general case for the `!` syntax). In this example, we go `u`p, then to the `l`ast child and to its `2`nd child’s `1`st child which leads to `(!ul21)`.

Each has its advantages, depending on how much static the tree actually is. If you move a lot around, it would be wise to give the nodes a fixed name. If one always keeps relative fixed to another node, you can use the relative node name. If a node always keeps relative to the root, you can use the special relative syntax after the tree (i.e. after the root node).

In the code below, I took the liberty to define a style `angled` that adds `<` and `>` automatically to its content. I also used another path for the connections (which I think looks a bit better but I’m not a linguist).

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{paths.ortho}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/16595
\forestset{angled/.style={content/.expanded={$<$\forestov{content}$>$}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} s sep*=3
[TP
  [DP, tikz={\draw[blue, ->] () -- node[sloped, above] {\ttfamily !ul21} (!ul21);}
    [John, triangle] ]
  [T'
    [T]
    [\emph{v}P
      [DP
        [John, triangle, angled] ]
      [\emph{v}'
        [\emph{v}
          [V
            [likes, name=V1] ]
          [\emph{v} ] ]
        [VP
          [V
            [likes, angled, name=V2] ]
          [DP
            [Mary, triangle] ] ] ] ] ] ]
%
\path[rounded corners, du, -latex] (!2211) edge (!11)
                                   (V2)    edge (V1);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]