# tikz-qtree does not work with node

Tags: nodes, tikz-qtree

I am trying to create a tree using the `tikz-qtree` package. But I keep getting the following error. `! Paragraph ended before \@@@@litlabel was complete.` Here is my tex-file:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=40pt]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\Tree [.IP 
        [.DP [.D $\emptyset$ ]
         [.NP [.N Sue ] ] ]
         [.I' [.I \node(i){has}; ]
          [.VP [.V \node(v){ }; ]
           [.VP [.V been ]
            [.VP [.VP [.V cooking ]
             [.DP [.D $\emptyset$ ]
              [.NP [.N pasta ] ] ] ]
               [.PP [.P in ]
                [.DP [.D the ]
                 [.NP [.N kitchen ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

\draw[semithick,->] (v)..controls +(east:1) and +(south:1)..(i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, if I am deleting the nodes inside the tree everyting compiles perfectly.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=40pt]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\Tree [.IP 
       [.DP [.D $\emptyset$ ]
        [.NP [.N Sue ] ] ]
         [.I' [.I has ] [.VP [.V ]
          [.VP [.V been ]
           [.VP [.VP [.V cooking ]
            [.DP [.D $\emptyset$ ]
             [.NP [.N pasta ] ] ] ]
              [.PP [.P in ]
               [.DP [.D the ]
                [.NP [.N kitchen ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The solution provided in [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144311/more-efficient-way-to-draw-movement-arrow-to-roof-in-tikz-qtree) does not help. Any ideas?

Comment: If instead of `\node(i){has};` I use `\node[name=i]{has};`, it works for me

Comment: @Ignasi It does not work for me.

Comment: Forget my previous comment, just add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to your preamble. It also works for me, even with `\node(i){has};`. It looks like as a conflict with `babel`.

Comment: @Ignasi `tikz-qtree 1.2` and `tikz 1.79`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a victim of `babel`. Add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` to escape.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,babel}    %%<-------------------
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=40pt]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\Tree [.IP
        [.DP [.D $\emptyset$ ]
         [.NP [.N Sue ] ] ]
         [.I' [.I \node(i){has}; ]
          [.VP [.V \node(v){ }; ]
           [.VP [.V been ]
            [.VP [.VP [.V cooking ]
             [.DP [.D $\emptyset$ ]
              [.NP [.N pasta ] ] ] ]
               [.PP [.P in ]
                [.DP [.D the ]
                 [.NP [.N kitchen ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

\draw[semithick,->] (v)..controls +(east:1) and +(south:1)..(i);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

It seems, you have old `tikz`. If you can't update put this in preamble.

```
\tikzset{
      every picture/.prefix style={
        execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{;}
      }
    }
```

Code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english, french, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{rotating}

\tikzset{
  every picture/.prefix style={
    execute at begin picture=\shorthandoff{;}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=40pt]
\tikzset{every tree node/.style={align=center,anchor=north}}
\Tree [.IP
        [.DP [.D $\emptyset$ ]
         [.NP [.N Sue ] ] ]
         [.I' [.I \node(i){has}; ]
          [.VP [.V \node(v){ }; ]
           [.VP [.V been ]
            [.VP [.VP [.V cooking ]
             [.DP [.D $\emptyset$ ]
              [.NP [.N pasta ] ] ] ]
               [.PP [.P in ]
                [.DP [.D the ]
                 [.NP [.N kitchen ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]

\draw[semithick,->] (v)..controls +(east:1) and +(south:1)..(i);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I keep getting the following error: `! I can't find file 'tikzlibrarybabel.code.tex'.`

Comment: @swot That means you don't the library installed. May be your version of tikz is old. Latest one is v3. Please update `tikz`.

Comment: @swot Please see the update for old `tikz` versions.

Comment: I updated my `tikz`and `babel` versions. Thank you.