# Arrow with text in Qtree or tikz-qtree?

Tags: arrows, syntax, tikz-qtree, qtree

I'm using qtree and I'm having problems making the arrow with the text as in the image below [image: tree]

Thanks ahead

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example? Finding out what the problem is will be much easier.

Comment: I'm still new to Latex. I haven't even tried to do it. I dunno how to make the arrows anyway.  The image was done using MS word.

Comment: So 'I'm using qtree' is, in fact, not true? And the problem is not the arrow but everything? That is, this is a do-it-for-me in disguise? There are lots of trees on this site. Please start with one of those.

Comment: Links at right immediately yield https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461279/drawing-movement-arrows-and-roofs-with-tikz-qtree?rq=1, for example.

Answer (score 1):

A starting point could be this MWE, but it is not very complete than your image. My suggestion is to use the guide here: https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree,

[image]

where you can also increase the angle of the tree and to add others details.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree,tikz-qtree-compat}
\begin{document}
\Tree [.A [.B ] 
          [.C [.D ] 
               [.E [.F ] 
                   [.G [.H ]  [.I ]]]]]
\end{document}
```