# Tikz library files at given path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using tikz library files from this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/vertical-and-horizontal-lines-in-pgf-tikz).

I use the code: `\usetikzlibrary{paths.ortho}`
and put files [tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code.tex](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code.tex) and [tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.tex](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.tex) in the root folder.

I wanted to know if it is possible to put the files into some other subfolder to utilise it? I just wanted to know it for better organization of my latex code.

Thanks !

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1137/15925 - these are just another type of "style" file.

Comment: i tried to put it in `my_root_dir/tex/latex/misc`, but it doesn't work. root_dir meaning, where my latex source code is present.

Comment: i want to keep it strictly to the source code where i am compiling the latex document, since I need to distribute it.

Comment: Usually you need to run `texhash`, or its equivalent on your system, once you have placed the files there so that latex will find them.

Comment: I did try running `texhash`, but I get an error message saying - `! I can't find file `tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code.tex'.
<argument> ...nput tikzlibrary\pgf@temp .code.tex 
                                                  \catcode `\@ =\csname tikz...
l.57 ...c,shapes, positioning,shadows,paths.ortho}
                                                  
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:`

Comment: @AndrewSwann This is not generally true. At least in TeX Live, if you install into your personal tree, running `texhash` is entirely superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\usetikzlibrary` does some additional checking, testing and house-keeping, but essentially you should  be able to just do

```
\makeatletter
\input{<subfolder>/tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code}
\makeatother
```

where `<subfolder>` stands for the relative path from your main `.tex` file to the sub-folder the library files lie in.

Answer (score 0):

See also this related question
[Add search path for \usetikzlibrary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/685186/add-search-path-for-usetikzlibrary), basically it is possible to add symlinks, or to use

```
\makeatletter
% Adds a subfolder to the search path
\def\input@path{{subfolder}}
% Tells tikz not to use its default input mechanism, but one that can recognize
% input@path
\let\pgfutil@IfFileExists     =\IfFileExists
\let\pgfutil@InputIfFileExists=\InputIfFileExists
\makeatother
```

then, use:

```
\usetikzlibrary{my.test}
```

as before (but it seems like libraries installed systemwide may have priority over `\input@path`… need to double check).