# Colorful Logic Gates using Circuitikz

Tags: color, circuitikz

I have to draw following circuit
[image]
the LaTeX source of which is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) node[not port] (not1) {}
(0,2) node[xor port] (xor1) {}
(0,4) node[and port] (and1) {}
(2,3) node[nor port] (nor1) {}
(4,2) node[xor port] (xor2) {}
(6,3) node[or port] (or1) {}
(6,1) node[and port] (and2) {}
(nor1.in 1) node[above](f) {U}
(nor1.in 2) node[below](g) {U}
(xor2.in 1) node[above](h) {U}
(xor2.in 2) node[below](i) {U}
(or1.out) node[right](j) {U}
(and1.out) -- (nor1.in 1)
(xor1.out) -- (nor1.in 2)
(nor1.out) -- (xor2.in 1)
(not1.out) -- (xor2.in 2)
(and1.out) -- (or1.in 1)
(xor2.out) -- (or1.in 2)
(xor1.out) -- (and2.in 1)
(not1.out) -- (and2.in 2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The circuit looks clumsy. What I want is that the gates whose inputs have been labelled `U` are drawn below the circuit such that the inputs wires of these circuits go downwards and then their outputs go upwards to the respective inputs.

The main question which I want to ask (which is also the title) is how to color the input and output wires of these gates red. By these gates I mean the gates whose inputs have been labelled `U`.

Will be very thankful even if slight help is offered.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The diagram would be improved alot by using connecting wires that are only horizontal or vertical.  There is a conveient syntax `|-` for a path that is first vertical then horizontal, and the corresponding `-|`.  You can apply colours to the individual symbols and to the connecting wires by specifying `color=red`.  Perhaps this is close to what you are after:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{circuitikz} \draw
(0,0) node[not port] (not1) {}
(0,2) node[xor port] (xor1) {}
(0,4) node[and port] (and1) {}
(2,3) node[nor port,color=red] (nor1) {}
(4,1) node[xor port,color=red] (xor2) {}
(6,3) node[or port,color=red] (or1) {}
(6,1) node[and port] (and2) {}
(nor1.in 1) node[above](f) {U}
(nor1.in 2) node[below](g) {U}
(xor2.in 1) node[left](h) {U}
(xor2.in 2) node[left](i) {U}
(or1.out) node[right](j) {U};
\draw[color=red] (and1.out) |- (nor1.in 1)
(xor1.out) |- (nor1.in 2)
(nor1.out) -| (xor2.in 1)
(not1.out) -| (xor2.in 2)
(xor2.out) |- (or1.in 2);
\draw 
(and1.out) -- +(4,0) |- (or1.in 1)
(xor1.out) -| (and2.in 1)
(not1.out) -| (and2.in 2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As the symbols are one unit, you can not (easily) change the colour an input wire right up to the symbol body.

Comment: Dear Friend, How can I show my gratitude! Thanks a lot. If possible would have given 100 bounty points, which is all I have.

Comment: @kamalbanga after a few days, your question will be eligible for a bounty :)

Comment: @cmhughes I will never be using LaTeX after a few days since my student life ends in two days. So I better use up my points. :)

Comment: Comments should not be used for discussions, but in that code you link to change `(xor2.out) -| (not2.in)` to `(xor2.out) |- (not2.in)`

Comment: Oh, silly mistake. Got it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with the `circuit` libraries of TikZ. We need the extra `-|-` and `|-|` styles from [Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/vertical-and-horizontal-lines-in-pgf-tikz) because the elements from `circuits.logic...` don't have pins.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  circuits,
  circuits.logic.IEC,
  circuits.logic.US,
  circuits.logic.CDH,
  calc
}
\tikzset{
  -|-/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) -| ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) |- (\tikztotarget)
      \tikztonodes
    }
  },
  -|-/.default=0.5,
  |-|/.style={
    to path={
      (\tikztostart) |- ($(\tikztostart)!#1!(\tikztotarget)$) -| (\tikztotarget)
      \tikztonodes
    }
  },
  |-|/.default=0.5,
}
\begin{document}
\newcommand\pic[1][circuit logic IEC]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
    \draw
    (0,0) node[not gate] (not1) {}
    (0,2) node[xor gate] (xor1) {}
    (0,4) node[and gate] (and1) {}
    (2,3) node[red,nor gate] (nor1) {}
    (4,2) node[red,xor gate] (xor2) {}
    (6,3) node[red,or gate] (or1) {}
    (6,1) node[and gate] (and2) {};
    \draw[red]
    (and1.output) to[-|-] (nor1.input 1) node[above left] {U}
    (xor1.output) to[-|-] (nor1.input 2) node[below left] {U}
    (nor1.output) to[-|-] (xor2.input 1) node[above left] {U}
    (not1.output) to[-|-] (xor2.input 2) node[below left] {U}
    (xor2.output) to[-|-] (or1.input 2)
    (or1.output) node[right] {U};
    \draw
    (and1.output) to[-|-] (or1.input 1)
    (xor1.output) to[-|-] (and2.input 1)
    (not1.output) to[-|-] (and2.input 2);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{frame}{circuit logic IEC}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pic
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{circuit logic US}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pic[circuit logic US]
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{circuit logic CDH}
  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \pic[circuit logic CDH]
  \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]