# Best way to draw line between two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a simply example to connect two node with a arrow line. but I doubt it's not the best way to do such things.

Requirement is:

1. Node location is fixed but maybe distance is unknow.
2. Connection line should be vertical or horizontal line.
3. Change direction between the middle of two nodes.

Current MWE as below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\tikzset{
    block/.style={draw,text width=2em,minimum height=1em,align=center},
    arrow/.style={->}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth'] 
    \node[block] (N1) {N1};
    \node[block,below=1cm of N1,xshift=-1cm] (N2) {N2};
    \path (N1) -- (N1 |- N2) coordinate [midway] (C);
    \draw [arrow] (N2) |- (C) -| (N1);
    \path[fill=red] (C) circle (2pt); % help dot,not must have
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Current Output is:

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45347)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `calc` library to avoid having to draw the path separately. Is this the kind of thing you want?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}

\tikzset{
  block/.style={draw,text width=2em,minimum height=1em,align=center},
  arrow/.style={->}
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
    \node[block] (N1) {N1};
    \node[block,below=1cm of N1,xshift=-1cm] (N2) {N2};
    \draw [arrow] (N2) |- ($(N1)!1/2!(N1 |- N2)$) coordinate (C) -| (N1);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: stepping up]

Or you could define a `pic`:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}

\tikzset{
  block/.style={draw,text width=2em,minimum height=1em,align=center},
  arrow/.style={->},
  pics/block connector/.style n args=2{
    code={
      \path [pic actions] (#1) |- ($(#2)!1/2!(#2 |- #1)$) -| (#2);
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
    \node[block] (N1) {N1};
    \node[block, below=1cm of N1, xshift=-1cm] (N2) {N2};
    \pic [draw=green, arrow] {block connector={N2.north west}{N1.north west}};
    \pic [draw=red, arrow] {block connector={N2.south east}{N1.south east}};
    \pic [draw=blue, arrow] {block connector={N1}{N2}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: pic block connectors]

Comment: Good answer, I am thinking about if it's possible to use chain library do it!

Comment: @Beatlej Thanks! I'm sure you can combine them but `chain`s do seem to be inherently unidirectional unless I've missed something. So you'd still need invisible nodes for the changes of direction, right? Just the change of direction would be for a chain?

Answer (score 2):

How about this one?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,calc}

\tikzset{
    block/.style={draw,text width=2em,minimum height=1em,align=center},
    arrow/.style={->}
}
\newcommand\connect[2]{\path[draw,arrow] (#1) |- ($(#1)!1/2!(#2)$) -| (#2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth']
    \node[block] (N1) {N1};
    \node[block,below=1cm of N1,xshift=-1cm] (N2) {N2};
    \connect{N1}{N2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result the same:
[image]