# TikZ: How to get 'Visio Connector tool' functionality in TikZ Picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Assume the MWE listed below.

This will produce the following picture. As you can see the vertical line is not 100% vertical.

[image: How to get this line vertically?]

**Question 1:** How do I say 'from point x go vertical up and connect to node y where exact anchor point at node y is unknown.' ?

**Question 2:** More general question: see screenshot below. What is the easiest way to make 'advanced' connections based on only vertical or horizontal lines? See the Blue line.

[image]

```
    \documentclass{minimal}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \tikzstyle{st1}=[rectangle, fill=white,draw=black,text centered, anchor=north, text=black, text width=4cm]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
        \node (Parent) [st1] { \textbf{Parent} };
      \node (hidden1) [text width=0.5cm, below=of Parent] {};    
        \node (Child) [st1,  right=of hidden1,xshift=-2cm] {\textbf{Child}};
        \draw (Child.west) -- ++(-0.2,0) -- ([ xshift=-0.8cm] Parent.south);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Very related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/vertical-and-horizontal-lines-in-pgf-tikz

Comment: Henri: Thanks for this link, however this one does not address my issue of the red line in the picture above. The vertical line is not 100% straight. So I am looking for a way to go straight up and connect to node X where it does reach it.

Comment: Probably [this question](tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279012/a-good-way-to-do-routing-in-logic-circuits-with-tikz-circuitikz) will help?

Answer (score 2):

If you load the `calc` library for some calculations and use Tikz operators, you can draw orthogonal paths with the required distances (`2mm` as in your question).

By the way:

- `draw=black` is usually not necessary, since it defaults to black, unless something else is creating conflicts. In that case, `draw=black` will help with the exception.
- No need to set a hidden node for positioning, just use the `positioning` library tools, like `below right`.
- Prefer the `standalone` class.
- Use `tikzset` for setting options, see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/4778)

### Output

[image: example image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\tikzset{
    st1/.style={draw,rectangle, fill=white, text centered, anchor=north, text width=4cm, font=\bfseries}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[node distance=1cm]

    \node (parent) [st1] {Parent}; 
    \node (child) [st1, below right=1cm and -2.5cm of parent] {Child};

    \draw[red, ultra thick] (child.west) -| ($(child.west|-parent.south)+(-2mm,0)$);
    \draw[blue!50!black, ultra thick] (child.east) -|
        ($(parent.north-|child.east)+(2mm,2mm)$) -|
        ($(parent.west)+(-2mm,0)$) |-
        (parent.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are there any advantages of using the `calc` library over `xshift`/`yshift` in this particular case?

Comment: @jak123 Not sure about actual differences, but I prefer the syntax: the code is shorter and easier to write/read.

Comment: I guess it is subjective then.

Comment: @jak123 Well, apart from the fact that you can do calculations you couldn't do otherwise. In this particular case, like I said, I can't think of any particular difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \begin{document}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \tikzstyle{st1}=[rectangle, fill=white,draw=black,text centered, anchor=north, text=black, text width=4cm]
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
        \node (Parent) [st1] { \textbf{Parent} };
      \node (hidden1) [text width=0.5cm, below=of Parent] {};    
        \node (Child) [st1,  right=of hidden1,xshift=-2cm] {\textbf{Child}};
        \draw (Child.west) -| ([xshift=-.8cm]Parent.south); %Question 1
        \draw (Parent.west) -| ++(-.5cm,1cm) -| ([xshift=.5cm] Child.east) -- (Child.east); %Question 2
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please [do not use the `minimal` class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided).

Comment: Thanks but this answer does not answer question 1. The 'direct' line from Child to Parent is still not straight vertical.

Comment: @robert I modified your code for this connector a little bit to address this point.