# rectangular merge edge of node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using nodes and edges to draw some trees (of proofs) and would like to have a rectangular merge of two nodes into another, something like

```
A          B
|          |
+----+-----+
     |
     C
```

From A to the cross point I could use (a) |- (cross) but what I really want is something like A |-| C.

Thanks

Norbert
(my first questions here I guess ;-)

Comment: See e.g. [Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/)

Comment: TikZ can draw trees. But I guess the *hip* thing today is to use `forest` package

Comment: @percusse For one, there's less typing involved. :P

Comment: We really need a complete example, though. **forest** is not really suitable for *graphs* as opposed to *trees*. If a single child has multiple parents, it is not a *tree* and may best be drawn in some other way. (Although you can sometimes use **forest** to good effect.)

Comment: You can't say `|-|` because it doesn't make sense. How would TikZ know *how much* vertical distance to do before the horizontal bit and how much after? `|-` and `-|` make sense because they say do *all* of the vertical then *all* of the horizontal or *vice-versa*.

Comment: You can as one sees in the solution linked in the first comment defining two styles |-| and -|-

Answer (score 1):

With **forest**, you can do something like this, but note that the root of the tree is now `C`. If the image in the question is a genuine tree, this must be the case because a child must have exactly one parent. If that's not the case, then it is a graph but it is not of the specific graph species tree. In that case, **forest** may not be the best option since it is dedicated specifically to the drawing of trees.

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}
\begin{document}
\forestapplylibrarydefaults{edges}
\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
    grow'=north,
  }
  [C[A][B]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: forked tree]

You can also use the `trees` TikZ library, although the syntax for specifying trees is considerably more verbose in that case.

Comment: Thanks, this looks nice and concise, I will check out the documentation, because I need also normal diagonal and unary vertical edges, too. I have for now used the solution from the vertical and horizontal lines in pgf solution with |-|, that works great.

Comment: @norbert You say e.g. `B, forked edge` and remove `forked edges` from the preamble of the tree to make just that particular edge forked.