# How do I turn a draw edge twice

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, edge

I want to connect two nodes with one edge so that it bends twice.

For instance,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \node  (A) {A};
        \node  (B) [below of=A] {B};

        \draw[->] (A.east) -- (B.east);


    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

will connect the two nodes with a straight line, but I want something like this

[image: wiw]

For this I would draw using `-|-` as a parameter to `\draw`, but that doesn't compile.

How can I get that line with two straight bends?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to achieve that is to draw a straight line from `A.east` towards right of the lenght you need (for example to `+(2em, 0)`) and then a corner (`|-`) to `B.east`.

Please also look at [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz).

```
\documentclass[border=4pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node  (A) {A};
        \node  (B) [below=3ex of A] {B};
        \draw[->] (A.east) -- +(2em, 0) |- (B.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does work. I'd prefer something less fiddly though, if it exists.

Comment: @MJGalram which part do you find "fiddly"?

Comment: `(A) -| ++(2em, -1em) |- (B);`

Comment: less fiddly I'd say especially if you skip the `em`s

Comment: well otherwise https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45347/vertical-and-horizontal-lines-in-pgf-tikz

Comment: @percusse Wow, I didn't know the tikzlibrary `paths.ortho`!

Answer (score 4):

Since you are looking for a draw operator (such as `-|-`): there's the [path.ortho](https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf) library by [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) for easily drawing such edges, just use `r-rl` in this case:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,paths.ortho}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node  (A) {A};
    \node  (B) [below=3ex of A] {B};
    \draw[->] (A.east) r-rl (B.east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]