# arrow to multipart rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, multipart-node

I want to do something like that:
[image]

But I'm having a hard time with the arrow. I was wondering if there was a way to do it without hardcoding every coordinates.

Here is the code of the multipart rectangle:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skip=2pt]{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing, shapes, arrows}
\settowidth{\textwidth}{Multipart rectangles with no line shortening}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,
rect/.style={
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=3,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split part fill={green!50,green!50,gray!50},
    draw=black,
    rounded corners,
    text width = 3cm
}]

% Split Rectangle
\node[rect] {
    \centerline{ether}
        \nodepart  {two} \centerline{ip}
        \nodepart[text width=5cm]{three}
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the manual, section 70.6 *Shapes with multiple text parts*, there are predefined anchors at the borders between the node parts. If you name your node `foo`, then `foo.two split north` is the point where your arrow is pointing to, so you can do

```
\draw [<-] (foo.two split north) -- +(0,1cm) node[above]{bar};
```

to get

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[skip=2pt]{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.pathreplacing, shapes, arrows}
\settowidth{\textwidth}{Multipart rectangles with no line shortening}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm,
rect/.style={
    rectangle split,
    rectangle split parts=3,
    rectangle split horizontal,
    rectangle split part fill={green!50,green!50,gray!50},
    draw=black,
    rounded corners,
    text width = 3cm,
    align=center % <- alternative to \centerline everywhere
}]

% Split Rectangle
\node[rect] (foo) {
    ether
    \nodepart  {two} ip
    \nodepart[text width=5cm]{three}
};

\draw [<-] (foo.two split north) -- +(0,1cm) node[above]{bar};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what I wanted!

Comment: I'm wondering, if I wanted to put the arrow between `ether` and `ip`. How should I do since there is no `foo.first` ? (also what manual are you talking about ? I searched for tikz manual on google but didn't found anything)

Comment: @irevoire That would be `foo.text split north`. The PGF & TikZ manual is [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf), see around page 796 (in version 3.1.1). You might be interested in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/495429/undefined-anchors-for-node-parts-in-a-tikz-split-rectangle) too.