# Path equivalent to -|- in Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I am making a diagram using Tikz in an attempt to match the one below.

[image: Example diagram to be replicated]

So far I have this:

[image: Replicated diagram]

My problem is that the two paths from each 'trigger' node going into the 'susceptibility' node only converge on the western side of it. How do I get them to converge in the middle of the gap like in the first image?
My code for the paths is as follows:

```
\path[draw]
    (trigger1.east) -| (susceptibility.west);
\path[draw]
    (trigger2.east) -| (susceptibility.west);
```

I understand that I need to have a path shape more like -|- rather than -| to achieve what I need, but I get an error saying 'cannot parse this coordinate' when using -|- . Is there any way to get a path with the -|- shape?

For context, I am using Overleaf.

This is my first time submitting a question here so please let me know if more info is needed or the images are broken.

Comment: Welcome. This is available in the paths.ortho library: https://github.com/Qrrbrbirlbel/pgf/blob/master/tikzlibrarypaths.ortho.code.tex

Comment: Welcome! Could you provide a MWE (Minimal Working Example) to implement your image, so that it's easier to come up with a solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110172/)

Comment: Thanks so much @Ross that's exactly what I needed :)