# Use Tikz \path [line] to draw three perpendicular lines from node to node?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I trying to draw a path from a node to another node using three perpendicular lines instead of two. Is there any method to do that?

My LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    % Define block styles
    \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5em, text centered]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \tikzstyle{input} = [trapezium, draw, minimum width=2cm, text width=3em, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=60, text centered]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm, auto]
        % Place nodes
        \node [input] (input) {Image};
        \node [process, right of=input] (bin_thresh_inv) {Binary threshold and invert};
        \node [process, right of=bin_thresh_inv] (draw_border) {Draw borders};
        \node [process, above right of=draw_border] (det_vert) {Detect vertical lines};
        \node [process, below right of=draw_border] (det_hor) {Detect horizontal lines};
        \node [process, below right of=det_vert, xshift=1.5cm] (gen_mask) {Generate mask and remove lines};

        % Draw edges
        \path [line] (input) -- (bin_thresh_inv);
        \path [line] (bin_thresh_inv) -- (draw_border);
        \path [line] (draw_border) |- (det_vert);
        \path [line] (draw_border) |- (det_hor);
        \path [line] (det_hor.east) -| (gen_mask.west);
        \path [line] (det_vert.east) |- (gen_mask.west);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Current result:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You might be interested in the `paths.ortho` TikZ library, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45347/86

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `+(0.5,0) |-` and `-| +(0.5,0)` to your path.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}

\begin{document}
    \centering
    % Define block styles
    \tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, draw, text width=5em, text centered]
    \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
    \tikzstyle{input} = [trapezium, draw, minimum width=2cm, text width=3em, trapezium left angle=120, trapezium right angle=60, text centered]
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3cm, auto]
        % Place nodes
        \node [input] (input) {Image};
        \node [process, right of=input] (bin_thresh_inv) {Binary threshold and invert};
        \node [process, right of=bin_thresh_inv] (draw_border) {Draw borders};
        \node [process, above right of=draw_border] (det_vert) {Detect vertical lines};
        \node [process, below right of=draw_border] (det_hor) {Detect horizontal lines};
        \node [process, below right of=det_vert, xshift=1.5cm] (gen_mask) {Generate mask and remove lines};
        
        % Draw edges
        \path [line] (input) -- (bin_thresh_inv);
        \path [line] (bin_thresh_inv) -- (draw_border);
        \path [line] (draw_border) |- (det_vert);
        \path [line] (draw_border) |- (det_hor);
        \path [line] (det_hor.east) -|  +(0.5,0) |- (gen_mask.west);
        \path [line] (det_vert.east) -| +(0.5,0) |-(gen_mask.west);     
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Explanation: With have 3 node A,B and C.
`\path [line] (a.east) -|  +(0.5,0) |- (b.west);` will connect `a.east` with `b.west` by going through the coordinate `(0.5,0)` (red line). `-|` just means horizontal line and vertical line.

If we write `(0.5,5)` you can see that the blue line overshoots since it is higher than the node itself.

In `\path [line,green] (c.north) |-  +(2,2) |- (b.west);` we leave north then go right passing the coordinate `(+2,2)`. The coordinate of our node c.north point is `(0,9)` plus `(2,2)` so the line goes through `(2,11)` marked with x. Then goes down `|` and connects with `b.west` (green).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
                
        \node[draw=black,minimum size=2cm] at (0,0) (a) {A};
        \node[draw=black,minimum size=2cm] at (4,4) (b) {B};
        \node[draw=black,minimum size=2cm] at (0,8) (c) {C};
        
        \path [line] (a.east) -|  +(0.5,0) |- (b.west);
        \path [line,red] (a.east) -|  +(1,0) |- (b.west);
        \path [line,green] (c.north) |-  +(2,1) |- (b.west);        
        
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how this works?

Comment: @Vinh Quang Tran I edited my answer for explanation.