# Does one need an invisible node to make edge split among nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I am learning how to make flow chart in tikz. In this MWE

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{NODE} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black, fill=red!10]
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]

\node (A1) [NODE]  {my first node};
\node (A2) [NODE,below of=A1]  {my second node};
\node (A3) [NODE,below of=A2]  {is it true?};
\node (A4) [NODE,left of=A3,yshift=-2cm]   {we get here if true};
\node (A5) [NODE,right of=A3,yshift=-2cm]   {we get here if false};

\draw [->,thick] (A1.south) -|   (A2.north);
\draw [->,thick] (A2.south) -| (A3.north);
\draw [->,thick] (A3.south) -| node[anchor=south] {YES} (A4.north);
\draw [->,thick] (A3.south) -| node[anchor=south] {NO} (A5.north);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It gives

[image]

I am not sure what is the correct way to produce this instead (which I did using paint.exe for illustration)

[image]

Do I need to make a hidden node below `A3` first? in order to make the edges as shown? Or is there a better and canonical way to do this? I do not want the edges to be sloping, I like to use straight edges only. I know I could do this

```
\draw [->,thick] (A1.south) -|   (A2.north);
\draw [->,thick] (A2.south) -| (A3.north);
\draw [->,thick] (A3.south) -- node[anchor=south] {YES} (A4.north);
\draw [->,thick] (A3.south) -- node[anchor=south] {NO} (A5.north);
```

And get

[image]

But I like the straight edges more.

Can one make a node in tikz that has no size and do not show, and use it just as place holder to in order to make edges to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Adaptations

- use relative positioning to move to the point below the node: `(A3.south) -- ++(0,-5mm)`
- save that point as `coordinate(a)` (this is the *invisible node without a size* you mention)
- reuse it to draw the other line `(a) -| ...`

  - I left out the first part (`(A3.south) -- (a)`) because it would just draw a second line over the already existing one. You would only need this, if you use curved edges or colored arrows.
- use `tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle` (see [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52372/123129))

#### See Also

- [Vertical and horizontal lines in pgf-tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/45347/123129)

#### Code

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=2cm,
    NODE/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black, fill=red!10}
]
    \node (A1) [NODE]  {my first node};
    \node (A2) [NODE,below of=A1]  {my second node};
    \node (A3) [NODE,below of=A2]  {is it true?};
    \node (A4) [NODE,left of=A3,yshift=-2cm]   {we get here if true};
    \node (A5) [NODE,right of=A3,yshift=-2cm]   {we get here if false};
    
    \draw [->,thick] (A1.south) -|   (A2.north);
    \draw [->,thick] (A2.south) -| (A3.north);
    \draw [->,thick] (A3.south) -- ++(0,-5mm) coordinate(a) -| node[anchor=south] {YES} (A4.north);
    \draw [->,thick] (a) -| node[anchor=south] {NO} (A5.north);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternative using `forest`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\useforestlibrary{edges}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, draw=black, fill=red!10,
  l sep=1cm, fork sep=5mm, s sep=1cm,
  forked edge, edge={thick, ->}
}
[my first node
  [my second node
    [is it true?
      [we get here if true, edge label={node[midway, above]{YES}}]
      [we get here if false, edge label={node[midway, above]{NO}}]
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, I will explore forest as it seems to simplify things.