# TikZ: small circle as an arrow tip

Tags: tikz-pgf

I know that the TikZ Arrow Tip Library (`arrows`) defines a circle arrow `[-o]`, however this circle is too large for me.  Is there any way I can control the size of the circle on the end of line?

Comment: I am interested at a solution too. What I do at this point is to define a circular node manually: `\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\radius{2pt}
\draw (0,0) -- (1,0) node [circle,radius=\radius,draw,fill=white,inner sep=\radius] {};
\end{tikzpicture}`

Comment: @Pygmalion Do you had checked the `pgflibraryarrows.code.tex`? If you change there the line `\pgfpathcircle{\pgfqpoint{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0bp}}{4.5\pgfutil@tempdima}` by other with a value less than 4.5 you will obtain what you want.

Comment: @rafaeldf I was thinking of that too, but I do not know where to find tikz codes.

Comment: @Pygmalion Try look at ...\tex\generic\pgf\libraries inside the folder that you had selected for installation (e.g., C:\Program Files\...).

Comment: it would be great to see a solution using `\tikzset{o=<options go here>}`, similar to how one can change the arrows easily using `\tikzset{>=stealth}` for example

Comment: seems very related: [how-do-i-make-a-path-with-a-custom-head-in-tikz](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46604/how-do-i-make-a-path-with-a-custom-head-in-tikz)

Comment: @cmhughes I've seen it and seems too complicated to adapt it to my problem.  If everything else fails, I might start cracking the code myself.  I posted the question in hope (from my previous experiences) that someone will have a solution as a piece of cake.

Comment: @cmhughes: That would be nice indeed, or even better, to have a general `arrow size` key. I've posted a bounty to that effect at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5461/is-it-possible-to-change-size-of-arrowhead-in-tikz-pgf

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the `decorations.markings` library to define a style (say, `o`) that takes an optional argument for changing the size:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    o/.style={
        shorten >=#1,
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark={
                at position 1
                with {
                    \draw circle [radius=#1];
                }
            }
        },
        postaction=decorate
    },
    o/.default=2pt
}
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\draw [o] (0,1) -- (4,3);
\draw [o=1pt] (1,1) -- (4,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not exaclty the same as [-o].  In [-o] circle **touches** the end of the path, while [o] draws circle **on the end** of the path...  I know that I have to add 2* befor #1 on line 3 of the definition, but I do not know how to calculate new position...

Comment: You can use `shorten >=2*#1` together with `\draw circle [xshift=-#1,radius=#1];`. The local coordinate system is rotated, so that `xshift` moves the mark in the direction of the line.

Comment: Hello Jake. I don't find how to get the circles at both tips of the line. Please could you help ?

Comment: Sorry I get it now. Just add a new mark with position=0. Thanks!

Comment: One problem is, it draws two arrow tips  with option `->`