# Custom arrow tip with `arrows.meta` TikZ library

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

In the spirit of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46604/how-do-i-make-a-path-with-a-custom-head-in-tikz), how do I make a custom arrow tip using the new `arrows.meta` TikZ library?  I would like to make a semicircular tip that accepts the `open` option, ideally, and perhaps other options like length (or radius or whatever the Circle arrow tip accepts).

Comment: A semicircular tip (as `Arc Barb[]`) is already opened...

Comment: @PaulGaborit: `Arc Barb` extends back onto the line.  I'd like it to like this `------------D` with the perpendicular edge and the open space.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to include answers. Either add an answer of your own or edit an existing one. The question space should be reserved for ..., well, questions, really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some improvements to Mark's answer so that semicircle is totally consistent with Circle.

```
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name=semicircle,
  defaults={
    length  = +2.39365pt +3.191538,
    line width = +0pt 1 1,
  },
  setup code={
    % Cap the line width at 1/2th of the length
    \pgf@x.5\pgfarrowlength
    \ifdim\pgf@x<\pgfarrowlinewidth
      \pgfarrowlinewidth\pgf@x
    \fi
    \pgfutil@tempdima.5\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgfutil@tempdima by-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth
    \pgfutil@tempdimb.5\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by.5\pgfarrowlinewidth
    \ifpgfarrowreversed
        \pgfarrowssetlineend{.5\pgfarrowlength\advance\pgf@x by-.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}
    \else
         \pgfarrowssetlineend{.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}
    \fi
    \pgfarrowssettipend{\pgfutil@tempdimb}
    % The hull:
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{0pt}{.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{0.20710678118\pgfarrowlength}{.5\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowsupperhullpoint{0.5\pgfarrowlength}{0.20710678118\pgfarrowlength}
    % The following are needed in the code:
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlinewidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfutil@tempdima
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfutil@tempdimb
  },
  drawing code = {
    \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin\pgfsetroundjoin\else\pgfsetmiterjoin\fi
    \ifdim\pgfarrowlinewidth=\pgflinewidth\else\pgfsetlinewidth{+\pgfarrowlinewidth}\fi
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}{\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{.5\pgfarrowlinewidth}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}}
    \pgfpatharc{-90}{90}{\pgfutil@tempdima}
    \pgfpathclose
    \ifpgfarrowopen\pgfusepathqstroke\else\ifdim\pgfarrowlinewidth>0pt\pgfusepathqfillstroke\else\pgfusepathqfill\fi\fi
  },
  parameters = {
    \the\pgfarrowlinewidth,%
    \the\pgfarrowlength,%
    \ifpgfarrowopen o\fi%
    \ifpgfarrowroundjoin j\fi%
  },
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The documentation for declaring new arrow tips is fairly comprehensive, but there appear to some errors in the examples. I'm not an expert on the `arrows.meta` stuff but the following appears to be the minimal requirements to get things started:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=0.25cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclarearrow{
  name=semicircle,
  parameters={ 
    \the\pgfarrowlength,%
    \ifpgfarrowopen o\fi%  
  },
  setup code={
    % The line end value:
    \pgfarrowssettipend{0pt}
    \pgf@x=-.25\pgfarrowlength
    \advance\pgf@x by-.5\pgflinewidth
    % The hull point:
    \pgfutil@tempdima=0.25\pgfarrowlength
    \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.5\pgflinewidth
    \pgfarrowssetlineend{\pgf@x}
    \pgfarrowssetvisualbackend{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssetbackend{-.75\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlength
    \pgfarrowlinewidth=\pgflinewidth
    \pgfarrowssavethe\pgfarrowlinewidth
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{0pt}{0pt}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{0pt}{-\pgfutil@tempdima}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{0pt}{\pgfutil@tempdima}
  },
  drawing code={
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.25\pgfarrowlength-.5\pgflinewidth}{.25\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-.25\pgfarrowlength-.5\pgflinewidth}{-.25\pgfarrowlength}}
    \pgfpatharc{-90}{90}{0.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfpathclose
    \ifpgfarrowopen\pgfusepathqstroke\else\ifdim\pgfarrowlinewidth>0pt\pgfusepathqfillstroke\else\pgfusepathqfill\fi\fi
  },
  defaults={ length=10pt }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] grid (3,2);
\draw [semicircle-{semicircle[open]}] (0,0) -- (3,2);
\draw [very thick, {semicircle[length=40pt,open]}-{semicircle[length=20pt]}] 
  (0,2) -- (3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Is there any way to make it so that the `border` is unnecessary?  The other arrow tips automatically extend the border.  No problem if that's difficult, but it's definitely nice to have :)

Comment: @NeilG just add `\pgfarrowshullpoint{0pt}{0pt}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{0pt}{-.25\pgfarrowlength}
    \pgfarrowshullpoint{0pt}{.25\pgfarrowlength}` to the `setup code`. The documentation explains what they do.

Comment: Hmm, I need to add `0.5 \pgflinewidth` I believe.  How do I do that?

Comment: You probably need to use a temporary dimension to do the calculation, for example, `\pgfutil@tempdima=0.25\pgfarrowlength \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.5\pgflinewidth \pgfarrowshullpoint{\pgfutil@tempdima}{\pgfutil@tempdima}`. Don't forget to change the catcode of `@` though.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know what "changing the catcode of @" means though :(

Comment: I incorporated your suggestions into your answer for the benefit of others.  Thanks again for making this solution perfect.