# TikZ: Define pattern with reference to external picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to fill a tikz-picture with a pattern, based on an external picture.
Is this possible? If yes, how?

I tried to define a new pattern with `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly`, but `\pgfuseimage` seems to be no valid command inside `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly`.

Remark:

- In my example I used a [marble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marble)-picture, but my question is independend from this special picture.
- I force the tile to 1cm. Probably it would be better to use the real size of the tile image.
- If I define `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly` after `\begin{document}` the LaTeX error disappear, but the pattern does not work.

My MNWE (minimal not working Example):

```
\documentclass[]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

%Source: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/de/thumb/f/f9/LapG.jpg/83px-LapG.jpg
%But could be any other picture
\pgfdeclareimage[width=1cm,height=1cm]{marble}{83px-LapG}%force quadratic tile

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{marble}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{1cm}}{
\pgfuseimage{marble}%! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% This should create a rectangle with 15*15 tiles.
\draw[pattern=marble] (0,0) rectangle (15,15);
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Inside a PGF picture, you will need to put `\pgfuseimage` inside a `\pgftext`. Though, this will still not show the image.

Comment: I think I found a [similar problem](http://fr.comp.text.tex.narkive.com/b75r5S5r/pgf-tikz-nouveau-pattern-texte-en-filigrane-dans-un-bandeau) with text as pattern. The corresponding question at [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/forums/forum/477362/topic/4885192?message=10924310) is unanswered.

Comment: I found [another (French) discussion](http://www.hilpers.fr/493104-pgf-utiliser-une-image-comme) in the net for this question. Result: It is not possible.

Comment: See also this related answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219356/how-to-create-a-rectangle-filled-with-image-using-tikz

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not possible with `pattern`, but with the `path picture` key and a few calculations.

*I have used patterns available at [texture-s.blogspot.de](http://texture-s.blogspot.de).*

---

I have turned the code into a small TikZ library which is part of my [`tikz-ext` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext).

Its usage can be seen below or in the manual.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, ext.patterns.images}
\pgfsetupimageaspattern[width=1cm]{marble}{marble.jpg}
\pgfsetupimageaspattern[width=2cm]{wall}{concretewall8.jpg}
\pgfsetupimageaspattern[width=2cm]{floor}{pattern4183.jpg}
\begin{document}
\tikz\matrix[column sep=2mm]{
  \path[image as pattern={name=marble}] (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
& \node[image as pattern={name=wall},star, star point ratio=2, minimum size=2cm] {};
& \path[even odd rule, image as pattern={name=floor}]
  (0,0) circle[radius=1cm] circle[radius=5mm];
& \draw[green, even odd rule, image as pattern={name=floor}]
  (0,0) circle[radius=1cm] circle[radius=5mm];
  \draw[blue, image as pattern={name=floor}]
    (-1cm, -1cm) (0,0) to[bend left] (2,1)
    --++(right:.1) to[bend left] (.1,0) -- cycle;
\\};
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's what I looked for. If possible, I would give you a 2nd +1 for texture-s.blogspot.de.

Comment: @knut You are welcome. While the first revision of my answer was merely a proof of concept, I have updated my answer with a small library, where maintaining more than one pattern is easier (the dimensions are calculated automatically).

Comment: That works great! But by any chance is it possible to apply it on the stroke of a circle? For instance if I do `\draw[image as pattern={left}, thick] (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];` then the inside of the node will be painted but the stroke will be black while I’d like no inside and a thick, image-filled, stroke. It would also be great to have it work with a width that fits the content.

Comment: Another thing that I often need: an image in absolute coordinate, so that if I draw two elements overlapping, the part where they overlap is the same.

Comment: @tobiasBora Using other than a solid line for a path itself is tricky (there are some Q&A around here somewhere). For a simple circle you can just a cutout, i.e. two circles with the `even odd rule`. For your second problem, either do everything on the same path or make sure that the both paths have the same lower-left bounding box corner, see the fourth example where `(-1cm, -1cm)` is the lower-left corner of the previous path.

Comment: Maybe it's also possible to install an actual pattern (that behave like that on their own) instead of this. There's also [`tikzfill`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzfill) but I haven't taken a look at that myself.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I just realized (see my new answer below) that `path picture` can do directly what I want for absolute positioning, and that tcolor box provides stuff like `fill tile image*` and `fill overzoom image=example-image-a` that basically mimics what you do in your answer.

Comment: @tobiasBora Yes, my answer/this library also only uses a `path picture` but with two loops to cover the whole area. I didn't really update this in the last 10 years.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible with PSTricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-fill}
\psboxfill{\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{example-image-A}}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(4,4)
    \pscircle[fillstyle=boxfill](2,2){2}
    \pscircle(2,2){2}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for a possible alternative solution. unfortunately not a TikZ-solution.

Answer (score 0):

For non-repetitive patterns, `path picture={\node{whatever thing to draw};}` offers a great flexibility, allowing you for instance to draw an image in background at absolute position. Otherwise, you can use the TikZ image fill extensions from the tcolorbox package as proposed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219356/how-to-create-a-rectangle-filled-with-image-using-tikz):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[fill overzoom image=example-image-a] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[fill stretch image=example-image-b] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\medskip

\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[fill tile image*={height=3cm}{example-image-c}] (0,0) rectangle (\textwidth,4cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

Absolute positioning:
% absolute coordinates
\noindent\begin{tikzpicture}
  [
    remember picture,
    absolute fill image/.style={
      path picture={
        \node[anchor=center] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{#1}};
      }
    }
  ]
  \path[draw=green,absolute fill image={example-image-b}] (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
  \path[draw=red,absolute fill image={example-image-b}] (.5,.5) circle[radius=1cm];
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```