# speckled colors in latex

Tags: beamer, color

I saw last week a presentation that was made with keynote and which was showing cells filled with speckled colours. Is there a way to get speckled colours in latex/beamer ? Until now I was only able to find uniform fills.

greetings, yves

SAM:
I would like to see some granularity in my fill:
http://www.arumugachemicals.com/images/seven_colors.jpg

Comment: What exactly do you mean with speckled colours? Can you show us an image?

Comment: You could use an image of the desired pattern as background to your cells. Offtopic: In my opinion thinks like pattern should only be used if they add additional information to the slides, e.g. if you are talking about a material of this texture. Otherwise this just adds noise to the slides and reduces the "ink"-to-information-ratio.

Comment: @samcarter - *reduces the information-to-ink-ratio

Comment: @MWc Upps :) Of course you are right!

Comment: I know, it doesn't carry any information, but it looks so fancy. :) If the only solution is to use an image, then it isn't worth the effort. Thank you for the answer anyway.

Comment: I think it should be possible using TikZ. More information about constructing a random pattern of dots can be found [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185012/how-to-have-a-real-random-pattern/185040#185040).

Comment: Have you never set through a presentation which was so fancy you couldn't read a word of what was on the screen? Such slides are worth less than nothing. With nothing, you'd focus on what was said. Such slides distract from the speaker while adding no value. They are also very, very annoying.

Comment: I see what you mean. It was not the case of the presentation I saw last week, where a slight pattern was used in a flow chart. I was thinking "god, that guy knows how to give a talk and choose his colours and patterns". I'm preparing a few templates I could use when I need to prepare a talk at the very last minute. So, I'm exploring. After a few trials, it is indeed possible to get similar patterns from MWc's hint and from the link he provided, but I did not yet find the efficient way to put it in a flow chart cell. I learned anyway a lot from the experience.