# Draw dotted background

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

Is it possible to fill a region with randomly allocated dots using TikZ or PSTricks? I can't imagine somebody manually assigning dots coordinate by coordinate.

Comment: I've seen this kind of figures using Tikz and others using PSTricks.

Comment: Note that the fill pattern repeats (it is not random). This means that you could define such a pattern in TikZ.

Comment: random filling patterns: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145969/filling-specified-area-by-random-dots-in-tikz/145975#145975

Comment: Also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185012/how-to-have-a-real-random-pattern/185158#185158

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a pattern I defined by taking the coordinates from your image. One could probably use some external program such as octave or the scripting capabilities of luatex to generate new points.

Just taking purely random points doesn't really work, because those won't be distributed evenly enough.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\pgfmathsetmacro\sprayRadius{.2pt}
\pgfmathsetmacro\sprayPeriod{.5cm}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{spray}{\pgfpoint{-\sprayRadius}{-\sprayRadius}}{\pgfpoint{1cm + \sprayRadius}{1cm + \sprayRadius}}{\pgfpoint{\sprayPeriod}{\sprayPeriod}}{
    \foreach \x/\y in {2/53,6/52,11/48,23/49,20/47,32/46,41/47,47/51,56/52,46/44,4/43,16/42,33/41,41/37,49/35,55/31,37/35,44/30,28/37,24/36,17/37,7/38,0/31,8/29,18/31,28/30,37/28,30/27,46/24,51/21,24/23,12/24,4/21,18/19,12/16,31/21,38/18,26/16,46/16,56/12,52/10,45/8,51/4,37/12,35/7,24/9,14/9,2/12,8/6,15/4,27/0,34/1,40/1} {
        \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{(\x + random()) / 57 * \sprayPeriod}{\sprayPeriod - (\y + random()) / 55 * \sprayPeriod}}{\sprayRadius}
    }
    %\foreach \i in {1,...,100} {
    %   \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{1cm * random()}{1cm * random()}}{\sprayRadius}
    %}
    \pgfusepath{fill}
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[pattern=spray] (0,0) -- (3,3) -- (2,3) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[border=4,pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=2,arrowscale=2}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(5,3)
\psaxes[labels=none,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-0.5)(4.5,2.5)[$x$,-90][$y$,180]
\psset{origin={1,0}}
\psRandom[dotsize=1pt,randomPoints=2000](3,3){%
    \psline[linestyle=none](0,0)(2.5;60)(3;45)(0,0)}
\psline(2.5;60)\psline(3;45)
\pscircle[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=white](0,0){2mm}
\Large\uput{4mm}[-90](1,0){1}
\psarc[arrows=->](0,0){0.5}{0}{45}\rput(1,0){\rput(0.75;22.5){$\frac{\pi}{4}$}}
\psarc[arrows=->](0,0){1}{0}{60}\rput(1,0){\rput(1.25;30){$\frac{\pi}{3}$}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]