# Drawing manifolds in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids, mapping

I know that there are other posts here addressing this issue, but none of them really made me able to draw the picture i have added below. I'm quite new to TikZ, so I would love to get some help with the drawing! What I intended to draw was not exactly what is shown in the picture, as that is probably not possible. I only want to draw a similar photo within the boundaries of TikZ. That is, the dots on the manifold surface are unnecessary, and the surfaces themselves don't have to curve exactly like the ones in the photo.

Update: The dots are possible, and have been added!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %\draw[smooth cycle,tension=3.0] plot coordinates{(1,0) (1,1) (2,2) (3,3) (6,0)} node [label=right:$M$];

    % Manifold
    \draw[smooth cycle, tension=0.4] plot coordinates{(2,2) (-0.5,0) (3,-2) (5,1)} node [label=$M$];

    % Help lines
    \draw[help lines] (-3,-6) grid (8,6);

    % Subsets
    \draw[smooth cycle] plot coordinates{(1,0) (1.5, 1.2) (2.5,1.3) (2.6, 0.4)} node [label={[label distance=-0.3cm, xshift=-1.8cm]:$U_i$}];

    \draw[smooth cycle] plot coordinates{(4, 0) (3.7, 0.8) (3.0, 1.2) (2.5, 1.2) (2.2, 0.8) (2.3, 0.5) (2.6, 0.3) (3.5, 0.0)} node [label={[left label distance=0.8cm, xshift=.65cm]:$U_j$}];

    % First Axis
    \draw[thick, ->] (-3,-5) -- (0,-5) node [label=above:$\phi_i(U_i)$];
    \draw[thick, ->] (-3,-5) -- (-3, -2) node [label=right:$\mathbb{R}^m$];

    % Second Axis
    \draw[thick, ->] (5, -5) -- (8, -5) node [label=above:$\phi_j(U_j)$];
    \draw[thick, ->] (5, -5) -- (5, -2) node [label=right:$\mathbb{R}^m$];

    % Functions
    \path[->] (0.93, -0.09) edge [bend right] node[right] {$\phi_i$} (-1, -3);
    \path[->] (-0.5, -3) edge [bend right] node [right] {$\phi^{-1}_i$} (1.093, -0.09);

    % Sets in R^m
    \draw[smooth cycle] plot coordinates{(-2, -4.5) (-2, -3.2) (-0.8, -3.2) (-0.8, -4.5)};
    \draw[smooth cycle] plot coordinates{(7, -4.5) (7, -3.2) (5.8, -3.2) (5.8, -4.5)};

    % Functions
    \path[->] (6.0, -3.0) edge [bend left] node[left] {$\phi^{-1}_j$} (3.8, -0.09);
    \path[->] (4.2, 0) edge [bend left] node[left] {$\phi_j$} (6.5, -3.0);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I don't know how to shade areas of the subsets with a grid as in the photo or how to prohibit the arrows etc. from intersecting each other.

Comment: `pgfplots`, maybe?

Comment: To add stippling, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266881/how-can-i-add-stippling-to-elements-of-my-tikz-diagrams

Comment: @JPi Thanks! I didn't think that was possible to achieve :)

Comment: Does anyone know how to add a grid to certain parts of the subsets though?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image]

I found a way to hatch the irregular regions with different patterns and to cut the arrows (so they do not overlap with region M). Also, I took the original image as reference, so my approach has some changes with respect yours. The available patterns in `pgfplots` are limited, but you can look for one that could meet your needs. [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114646/where-is-the-pattern-list-gallery-for-pgfplots) is a reference of them.

It was hard but finally got it. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns, positioning, arrows}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Functions i
    \path[->] (0.8, 0) edge [bend right] node[left, xshift=-2mm] {$\phi_i$} (-1, -2.9);
    \draw[white,fill=white] (0.06,-0.57) circle (.15cm);
    \path[->] (-0.7, -3.05) edge [bend right] node [right, yshift=-3mm] {$\phi^{-1}_i$} (1.093, -0.11);
    \draw[white, fill=white] (0.95,-1.2) circle (.15cm);

    % Functions j
    \path[->] (5.8, -2.8) edge [bend left] node[midway, xshift=-5mm, yshift=-3mm] {$\phi^{-1}_j$} (3.8, -0.35);
    \draw[white, fill=white] (4,-1.1) circle (.15cm);
    \path[->] (4.2, 0) edge [bend left] node[right, xshift=2mm] {$\phi_j$} (6.2, -2.8);
    \draw[white, fill=white] (4.54,-0.12) circle (.15cm);

    % Manifold
    \draw[smooth cycle, tension=0.4, fill=white, pattern color=brown, pattern=north west lines, opacity=0.7] plot coordinates{(2,2) (-0.5,0) (3,-2) (5,1)} node at (3,2.3) {$M$};

    % Help lines
    %\draw[help lines] (-3,-6) grid (8,6);

    % Subsets
    \draw[smooth cycle, pattern color=orange, pattern=crosshatch dots] 
        plot coordinates {(1,0) (1.5, 1.2) (2.5,1.3) (2.6, 0.4)} 
        node [label={[label distance=-0.3cm, xshift=-2cm, fill=white]:$U_i$}] {};
    \draw[smooth cycle, pattern color=blue, pattern=crosshatch dots] 
        plot coordinates {(4, 0) (3.7, 0.8) (3.0, 1.2) (2.5, 1.2) (2.2, 0.8) (2.3, 0.5) (2.6, 0.3) (3.5, 0.0)} 
        node [label={[label distance=-0.8cm, xshift=.75cm, yshift=1cm, fill=white]:$U_j$}] {};

    % First Axis
    \draw[thick, ->] (-3,-5) -- (0, -5) node [label=above:$\phi_i(U_i)$] {};
    \draw[thick, ->] (-3,-5) -- (-3, -2) node [label=right:$\mathbb{R}^m$] {};

    % Arrow from i to j
    \draw[->] (0, -3.85) -- node[midway, above]{$\psi_{ij}$} (4.5, -3.85);

    % Second Axis
    \draw[thick, ->] (5, -5) -- (8, -5) node [label=above:$\phi_j(U_j)$] {};
    \draw[thick, ->] (5, -5) -- (5, -2) node [label=right:$\mathbb{R}^m$] {};

    % Sets in R^m
    \draw[white, pattern color=orange, pattern=crosshatch dots] (-0.67, -3.06) -- +(180:0.8) arc (180:270:0.8);
    \fill[even odd rule, white] [smooth cycle] plot coordinates{(-2, -4.5) (-2, -3.2) (-0.8, -3.2) (-0.8, -4.5)} (-0.67, -3.06) -- +(180:0.8) arc (180:270:0.8);
    \draw[smooth cycle] plot coordinates{(-2, -4.5) (-2, -3.2) (-0.8, -3.2) (-0.8, -4.5)};
    \draw (-1.45, -3.06) arc (180:270:0.8);

    \draw[white, pattern color=blue, pattern=crosshatch dots] (5.7, -3.06) -- +(-90:0.8) arc (-90:0:0.8);
    \fill[even odd rule, white] [smooth cycle] plot coordinates{(7, -4.5) (7, -3.2) (5.8, -3.2) (5.8, -4.5)} (5.7, -3.06) -- +(-90:0.8) arc (-90:0:0.8);
    \draw[smooth cycle] plot coordinates{(7, -4.5) (7, -3.2) (5.8, -3.2) (5.8, -4.5)};
    \draw (5.69, -3.85) arc (-90:0:0.8);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** I found this random dotted pattern created by **@wrtlprnft** in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308805/draw-dotted-background?noredirect=1&lq=1). You just need to write down the following code in the preamble and replacing pattern's name by `spray` in the original diagram. (I tunned it by changing `\sprayRadius{.25pt}` and `\sprayPeriod{.6cm}`).

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\sprayRadius{.25pt}
\pgfmathsetmacro\sprayPeriod{.6cm}

\pgfdeclarepatternformonly{spray}{\pgfpoint{-\sprayRadius}{-\sprayRadius}}{\pgfpoint{1cm + \sprayRadius}{1cm + \sprayRadius}}{\pgfpoint{\sprayPeriod}{\sprayPeriod}}{
    \foreach \x/\y in {2/53,6/52,11/48,23/49,20/47,32/46,41/47,47/51,56/52,46/44,4/43,16/42,33/41,41/37,49/35,55/31,37/35,44/30,28/37,24/36,17/37,7/38,0/31,8/29,18/31,28/30,37/28,30/27,46/24,51/21,24/23,12/24,4/21,18/19,12/16,31/21,38/18,26/16,46/16,56/12,52/10,45/8,51/4,37/12,35/7,24/9,14/9,2/12,8/6,15/4,27/0,34/1,40/1} {
    \pgfpathcircle{\pgfpoint{(\x + random()) / 57 * \sprayPeriod}{\sprayPeriod - (\y + random()) / 55 * \sprayPeriod}}{\sprayRadius}
    }
\pgfusepath{fill}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Great picture. Note however that the colors in the lower pictures should be swapped (Ui represents the red area and you should see the blue dots in the overlap etc.). Anyway that's easy to adjust and really well done!

Comment: @LFH To be painfully nit picky, that's not entirely true. It is the intersection of U_i and U_j that the transition functions \psi_{ij} maps from and to. I.e., \psi_{ij}: \phi_i(U_i\cap U_j) \to \phi_j(U_i \cap U_j), but that's not part of the TeX-question anyway.

Comment: What other patterns for the colored regions are there in the original code?

Comment: To fully convey what's happening mathematically, the patterns on the two sets in $\mathbb{R}^m$ should consist of horizontal/vertical grids, and then the corresponding patches on the manifold should be curved.