# Repeating texture renders with lines between the instances

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, pdf

Assume I have some repeating texture file `texture.png`. I use it like this (ConTeXt, but I assume using LaTeX would not really make a difference):

```
\usemodule[tikz]

\starttext
  \starttikzpicture[x=1mm,y=1mm, every node/.style={font={\ss\bfb}}, remember picture, overlay]

    \foreach \x in {0,9,...,63}{
      \foreach \y in {0,9,...,63}{
        \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0,outer sep=0] at (\x,\y) {
          \externalfigure[texture.png][width=9mm,height=9mm]
        };
      }
    }
  \stoptikzpicture
\stoptext
```

Now when I open the resulting PDF with Preview (macOS), it renders fine. However, when I open the PDF with Adobe Reader, there are fine lines between the instances of the texture.

I create this PDF in order to print it. Do I need to worry about those lines being printed, or are they just rendering artifacts? I could try with my printer, but I will send the PDF to a printing service eventually, so I want to be sure that this is not a problem for *any* printer.

Comment: (I do not use ConTeXt.) Did you try using a pattern for that? It might be faster and easier to control. (I stress that I have not tried myself, so the comment may not help at all, it is really just the question of whether or not you have tried.)

Comment: @marmot I use textures from [here](https://www.transparenttextures.com/), I have no idea how I would translate these into a pattern. A quick search brought up [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107144/11150), however that looks far more complicated than what I'm doing so I'd rather avoid it if it's not necessary.