# Disable image interpolation when repeating texture using PGF

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I am trying to use a PNG image as repeating texture with TikZ, using the solution posted [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107144/11150).

By using a smaller texture than what the examples there seem to use, I noticed that this method produces lines at the edges of the texture (zoomed in):

[image]

This seems to be a result of interpolation and I want to get rid of it. I tried to explicitly disable it with

```
\pgfSetupImageAsPattern[width=3cm,interpolate=false]{wall}{smooth-wall-dark.png}
```

However, that did change nothing (not surprisingly, since *interpolate* is documented to be *false* by default). How do I disable interpolation here so that the texture does not have these lines? I am aware that this will make the texture more pixel-y.

Comment: This might actually be a viewer issue.  Can you try different viewers?

Comment: Original image was macOS Preview. Adobe yields [this](https://flyx.org/files/pgf-image-adobe.png), so you seem to be right, although I don't quite understand what's happening in Adobe (one tile suddenly has a darker color?!). Sadly, I tried this as workaround for my [original issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/473524/11150), which was also about viewers being unreliable. *sigh* I probably need to expand the PNG graphic externally before including it to get rid of these issues.

Comment: Well, PDF viewers are always kind of hit and miss.  Another thing you might be interested in is: How does it print?  Do you see glitches in the printout?  If yes, something has to be done.

Comment: Those fine lines and darker tiles probably depend on the zoom level.  Does it change as you zoom in and out?

Comment: Yes, zoom level changes it. Regarding printing: As I described in my other question, I want to give the PDF to a printing service finally, so I want to be content that it properly prints there and since they will have quite a different printer than I do, I can hardly trust it more than the PDF viewer.

Comment: You could try rasterizing the PDF with 300 DPI and see if it's still bad, because that's roughly what a printer does.

Comment: Good idea, will try that.