# Tikzcd: Filling node with image pattern fails if I apply it on all cells at once

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, fill

I'm trying to fill some pictures with a background image using `path picture` as recomended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/219356/how-to-create-a-rectangle-filled-with-image-using-tikz) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103980/tikz-define-pattern-with-reference-to-external-picture). It works great if I put the style in the cell directly like `|[path card]| my content`, but it does not compile if I put it inside `cells={nodes={path card}}`. Any idea what's wrong?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd,calc,positioning,shadows}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  path card/.style={
    path picture={
      \node[] at (path picture bounding box.center) {
        \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}};}},
}
{
  \begin{tikzcd}[
    nodes in empty cells,
    column sep=1mm,
    row sep=1mm,
    cells={
      nodes={
        inner sep=0pt,
        minimum width=3.9mm,
        minimum height=6mm,
        drop shadow,
        draw,
        fill=white,
        rounded corners=2pt,
        anchor=center,
        shape=rectangle,
        font={\fontsize{4}{12}\selectfont},
        %path card, %% <- uncomment this line, everything breaks.
      }
    },
    ]
     |[path card]| &  & [1mm] & \\
                   &  &       & \\[1mm]
                   &  &       & \\
                   &  &       &
  \end{tikzcd}
}%


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define a style(options) for all nodes, that contain a `path picture` that contain a `node` that contain... - problems. Break the infinite recursion with `path picture=none` (or rather `path picture` alone to avoid a warning).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadows}

\tikzset{
  path card/.style={
    path picture={
      \node[path picture] at (path picture bounding box.center) {
        \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image}};}},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [
matrix of  nodes,
nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=1mm,
    row sep=1mm,
      nodes={
        inner sep=0pt,
        minimum width=3.9mm,
        minimum height=6mm,
        drop shadow,
        draw,
        fill=white,
        rounded corners=2pt,
        anchor=center,
        shape=rectangle,
        font={\fontsize{4}{12}\selectfont},
        path card,
    },
]{
 & &[1mm]  &\\
 & & &\\[1mm]
 & & &\\
 & & &\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 16 rectangles with example image]

Comment: `path picture=none` is not correct after all, as it creates warnings. Just `path picture` seems to work.

Comment: oh, good point, thanks! I did not realized that the `every node` would also apply to this node ^^ Thanks! (also, I applied your comment as an edit since it seems to work)